# How to avoid temporary variables in PHP when using an array returned from a function

Tags: php, arrays

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP syntax for dereferencing function result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/742764/php-syntax-for-dereferencing-function-result)

The use of `$tmp` below is pretty ugly.  Is there a way to avoid it?

```
function test()
{
  return array('a'=>1, 'b'=>2);
}

$tmp = test();
echo "This should be 2: ", $tmp['b'], "\n";
```

Is there some reason the natural

```
test()['b']
```

doesn't work?