# Access array element from function call in php

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to avoid temporary variables in PHP when using an array returned from a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1769020/how-to-avoid-temporary-variables-in-php-when-using-an-array-returned-from-a-func)

```
function array_test()  
{ 
    return array(0, 1, 2); 
}  

echo array_test()[0];
```

Can anyone explain why this code doesn't work?