# Access to array $this->session->array

Tags: php, arrays

How can i access an array like this `$this->session->userdata('auth')` ?

print_r() displays:

```
Array (
  [ncli] => 0
  [nomecli] => somename 
  [nomcli1] => Administrador 
  [morcli] => company 
  [nuser] => admin 
  [pwdcli] => pwdadmin 
)
```

But I can't use `$this->session->userdata('auth')[ncli]`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put it in a variable:

```
$data = $this->session->userdata('auth');
echo $data['ncli'];
```

The reason why you can't do `()[]` is that [PHP just doesn't support it yet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2282051/access-array-element-from-function-call-in-php).

Comment: i know i can do that, should have mentioned. but isn't there a direct way?

Comment: @nosuchnick: Not at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

You will be able to do so from PHP 5.4 where they've introduced array dereferencing. Till then use an auxiliary variable.

```
$auth = $this->session->userdata('auth');
$auth['ncli'];
```

Comment: Yes http://schlueters.de/blog/archives/138-Features-in-PHP-trunk-Array-dereferencing.html

Comment: Cool, I thought we'd still have to wait till 6 no matter what the next minor 5 release was.