# PHP Function -> Array

Tags: php, class, function

I have a PHP function which populates a multi-dimensional array

```
$client->getResponse()
```

I want to utilise that array directly, something like this:

`echo '$client->getResponse()[0]';` which obviously doesn't work.

I don't want to have to do this

`$arr = array($client->getResponse());` as that brings in another level of array which I don't really want.

Comment: Sadly, this is not possible in PHP. The only alternative is method chaining (available since PHP 5)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Access array element from function call in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2282051/access-array-element-from-function-call-in-php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$arr = $client->getResponse();
echo $arr[0];
```

should suffice.

You can display every item inside the array with a `foreach`

```
foreach($client->getResponse() as $clientResponse){
    echo $clientResponse;
}
```

Comment: @Pekka : I don't see how it doesn't answer it... It doesn't *bring another array level* and can be used *directly*. Hence, if he got access to his class he could do a chaining : `echo $client->getResponse()->get(1);` for example.

Comment: I'm calling this best response because it is. Works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

What about introducing a tmp?

```
$tmp = $client->getResponse();
echo $tmp[0];
```

Comment: That's what he says he doesn't want to have to do

Comment: Wait a second: "$arr = array($client->getResponse()); as that brings in another level of array which I don't really want." The only problem here is the array function.

Answer (score 0):

Attention, if you use:

```
foreach($client->getResponse() ...)
```

The function ''getResponse'' will be execute in each iteration... If the data change during the "each" process, you may have incoherent values. No ?

Comment: Not true. The method will be called only once.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you create another method for the class that $client represents?  maybe "GetResponseEntry($id)", like so:

```
function getResponseEntry( $id, $default = null )
{
    static $response = null;

    if( $response === null )
        $response = $this->getResponse();

    if( isset($response[$id]) )
        return $response[$id];
    else
        return $default;
}
```

Then you could call it like so:

```
echo $client->getResponseEntry(0);
```

It may not be suitable for all circumstances, but ... maybe, just maybe, it'll work here.