# explode without variables

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Access array element from function call in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2282051/access-array-element-from-function-call-in-php)

instead of doing this:

```
$s=explode('.','hello.world.!');
echo $s[0]; //hello
```

I want to do something like this:

```
echo explode('.','hello.world.!')[0];
```

But doesn't work in PHP, how to do it? Is it possible? Thank you.

Comment: http://codepad.viper-7.com/xunFUI

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the oneliners say, you'll have to wait for array dereferencing to be supported. A common workaround nowadays is to define a helper function for that `d($array,0)`.

In your case you probably shouldn't be using the stupid `explode` in the first place. There are more appropriate string functions in PHP. If you just want the first part:

```
echo strtok("hello.world.!", ".");
```

Answer (score 3):

Currently not but you could write a function for this purpose:

```
function arrayGetValue($array, $key = 0) {
    return $array[$key];
}

echo arrayGetValue(explode('.','hello.world.!'), 0);
```

Answer (score 3):

It's not pretty; but you can make use of the [PHP Array functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php) to perform this action:

```
$input = "one,two,three";

// Extract the first element.
var_dump(current(explode(",", $input)));

// Extract an arbitrary element (index is the second argument {2}).
var_dump(current(array_slice(explode(",", $input), 2, 1)));
```

The use of `array_slice()` is pretty foul as it will allocate a second array which is wasteful.

Comment: +1 for being able to access an nth element. I never thought of doing this!

Comment: does current() works with non-variables ?

Comment: The above code was executed successfully by PHP 5.3.6 on the CLI.

Answer (score 2):

Not at the moment, but it [WILL be possible](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/functionarraydereferencing) in later versions of PHP.

Answer (score 2):

While it is not possible, you technically can do this to fetch the 0 element:

```
echo array_shift(explode('.','hello.world.!'));
```

This will throw a notice if error reporting E_STRICT is on.:
`Strict standards: Only variables should be passed by reference`

Comment: can use `echo current(explode('.','hello.world.!'));` which doesnt raise the E_STRICT message.

Comment: I never really use the `current()` and `end()` functions, but I probably should look over them again.

Comment: funny enough, end() does raise E_STRICT

Answer (score 2):

This will be possible in PHP 5.4, but for now you'll have to use some alternative syntax.

For example:

```
list($first) = explode('.','hello.world.!');
echo $first;
```

Answer (score 1):

nope, not possible. PHP doesn't work like javascript.

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not possible. I had similar question before, but it's not