# How to write two lines of code as one

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [explode without variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7221158/explode-without-variables)

```
$domainArray = explode('.', $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
$domainname = $domainArray[1];
```

I have to run these 2 lines of code on many pages of a site - above code works fine.

I want to change it into one line and have tried many times unsuccessfully.

Any ideas?

Comment: What version of PHP are you running?

Comment: eh why exactly does it need to be one line?

Comment: If you have this on many pages then you'd better write a function for it that has a name that reflects the meaning of the code, e.g. getDomainName(). Then it does not really matter any more how many lines it will take, and you can write a nice PHPDoc description for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work with PHP < 5.4:

```
list(,$domainname) = explode('.', $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
```

Answer (score 3):

with PHP 5.4 you can write just:
`$domainArray = explode('.', $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])[1]`

also you can write function like this

```
function getByIndex($array, $index) {
    return $array[$index];
}

$domainname = getByIndex(explode('.', $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']), 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd just make it a function and have it return the Domain Name...

Answer (score 1):

PHP < 5.4

```
// 2 is the index of the element you want to access
current(array_slice(explode(",", $input), 2, 1)));
```

Answer (score 1):

This isn't exactly the same because:
-yours strips the leftmost subdomain
-returns the tld in the event of no subdomain

anyway

```
echo $host = parse_url($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERRER'], PHP_URL_HOST);
```