# Parse error on explode('-','foo-bar')[0] (for instance)

Tags: php, parsing

Why doesn't php support this syntax:

```
$s = explode('-', 'foo-bar')[0];
```

?

Comment: [Array Dereferencing is in trunk now](http://schlueters.de/blog/archives/138-Features-in-PHP-trunk-Array-dereferencing.html)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to avoid temporary variables in PHP when using an array returned from a function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1769020/how-to-avoid-temporary-variables-in-php-when-using-an-array-returned-from-a-func)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's a limitation in the PHP parser. There's no reason why it can't support this form of reduction, it just doesn't.

Answer (score 5):

You can write it using [`list`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.list.php):

```
list($first_value) = explode(‘-’,‘foo-bar’);
```

Comment: Yes, of course, but I was just wondering why it doesn't work in the case of php

Answer (score 0):

The syntax `‘foo-bar’)[0]` is wrong as far as php is concerned. I don't know which language you have seen such thing in but PHP has no implementation for such syntax. However, you can split your string like this:

```
explode(‘-’, ‘foo-bar’);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead you could use this if you'r force to use inline : 
substr($var,0, strrpos($var,'-')); 
But I prefer the list solution , it's more elegant !

---