# Why are functions indexable in Python but not PHP?

Tags: php, python, programming-languages

I don't mean for this question to be about Python vs PHP but about languages in general.  I use Python and PHP as examples because I know them.

In Python we can do `mytoken = mystring.split(mydelimiter)[1]`, accessing the list returned by `str.split` without ever assigning it to a list.
In PHP we must put the array in memory before accessing it, as in `$mytokenarray = explode($mydelimiter, $mystring); $mytoken = $mytokenarray[1];`.  As far as I know it is not possible to do this in one statement as in Python.

What is going on behind this difference?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parse error on explode('-','foo-bar')\[0\] (for instance)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2396782/parse-error-on-explode-foo-bar0-for-instance)

Comment: Yes, it is basically a duplicate of that question.

Comment: [Array Dereferencing is in trunk now](http://schlueters.de/blog/archives/138-Features-in-PHP-trunk-Array-dereferencing.html)

Comment: Functions are not indexable in any language that I've ever heard of. You mean "expressions".

Comment: There are a lot of false assumptions in the question. The example is not indexing the function. It is indexing the return value of the function. In PHP assigning a variable to a value does not "put the array in memory before accessing it". The array is already in memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you try to do this in php

```
$mytokenarray = explode($mydelimiter, $mystring)[1];
```

notice the error you get: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '['`.

This means that php is getting upset when it tries to parse the code, not when it tries to execute it. I suspect that means that php's grammar (which, I hear rumored, is generated on the fly though I really have no idea) says that you can't put '[' after a `statement` or `expression` or whatever they call it. Rather, you can probably only put '[' after a variable.

Here's Python's grammar. http://docs.python.org/reference/grammar.html which contains the rule `trailer: '(' [arglist] ')' | '[' subscriptlist ']' | '.' NAME` From there you can see that `trailer` is part of `atom` which can also contain `[`. You're starting to get the picture that it's pretty complicated.

Blah blah blah, long story short, learn about compilers, or even better, write one for a toy language. Then you will have loads of insight into language quirks.

Comment: Or, put more controversially: PHP's grammar is very weird/full of special cases. In sane languages, referencing a variable is just another expression...

Answer (score 1):

It is a design decision the authors of the languages chose to make. Generally spoken (and this is of course not always the case) the nicer the syntax a language has the slower it tends to be. Case in point: Ruby.

Comment: This makes no sense.  For any compiled language, of course, the syntax disappears at runtime.  And for interpreted languages—well, take Ruby.  A source file is loaded and parsed *before* it is run, so even if parsing *were* much slower (something I'm not convinced of), this would only be a problem *once per file*.  And PHP here is not making things "nicer", just less regular.

Comment: I wonder if it's more to the point to say that the nicer the syntax is the more difficult the compiler is to write.

Comment: Niceness is a complicated thing. Some of it won't affect neither compiler nor speed, some will affect compiler complexity (affecting speed of interpreted languages) and some will affect runtime performance. Examples: I'd imagine that not requiring semicolons at the end of lines won't affect complexity nor performance since you just use the `\n` instead of `;`. Not requiring type declarations in a statically typed language increases compiler complexity since it has to infer the types. Dynamically typed languages are slower at runtime because method calls must be looked up at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

This feature is now possible with PHP as of version 5.4.