# PHP syntax error when accessing a function return value with [0]

Tags: php

Originally this code worked on my personal development server:

```
$id = str_split(md5(mt_rand()), 16)[0];
```

But on another server, (same version of Apache and PHP, I do not know what the remote php.ini looks like), the code threw this error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' ...
```

I "fixed" the issue by changing the code to:

```
$id = str_split(md5(mt_rand()), 16);
$id = $id[0];
```

Then later changed back to the original to try and hunt down the problem - but the original code worked! Why would that first line of code throw a syntax error? I have tried searching for an explanation but I do not know what to call this type of issue.

Comment: iirc, php's parser is completely insane and doesn't express things like this in the simpler terms of "expression followed by `[0]`"; rather as "variable followed by `[0]`".  there's no deeper reason than that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parse error on explode('-','foo-bar')\[0\] (for instance)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2396782/parse-error-on-explode-foo-bar0-for-instance)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using direct array dereferences like that was not added until PHP 5.4.

You will have to assign to a temporary variable:

```
$arr = your_function();
$value = $arr[0];
```

see Example #7 here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Comment: This perfectly explains my issue, thank you!