# Casting an Array with Numeric Keys as an Object

Tags: php, arrays, casting

I was poking around PHPs casting mechanism, and ran into an odd case when casting an array as an object

```
$o = (object) array('1'=>'/foo/bar');   
$o = new stdClass();
var_dump($o);
```

As I understand it, PHP properties need to be declared with the same rules as PHP variables.  That is [A valid variable name starts with a letter or underscore, followed by any number of letters, numbers, or underscores](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php).  However, the above code produces the following output

```
object(stdClass)#1 (1) {
  [1]=>
  string(8) "/foo/bar"
}
```

Where it gets really weird is when you try to access that information in the object.

```
var_dump($o->1);        // parse error
var_dump($o->{'1'});        // NULL 
var_dump(get_object_vars($o));  //array(0) { }
```

Is there anyway to get at the the information that var_dump reports is in the object, or is it just locked up for the rest of the request life cycle? (practical use of this is nil, I'm just curious)

Comment: From my experience it seems like they are locked away although I've never been adamant enough to try everything.

Comment: this is in fact the case, it's a known issue in PHP.

Comment: Is that known as in known by us, or known as in acknowledged in some way by the PHP team.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, they are just locked away unless cast back to an array.  There are a few little "Gotchas" in PHP, for example in older versions you could define a constant as an array, but then never access its elements.  Even now you can define a constant as a resource (e.g., `define('MYSQL',mysql_connect());`) although this leads to rather unpredictable behavoir and, again, should be avoided.

Generally, it's best to avoid array-to-object casts if at all possible.  If you really need to do this, consider creating a new instance of `stdClass` and then manually renaming all the variables, for example to `_0`, `_1`, etc.

```
$a = array('cat','dog','pheasant');
$o = new stdClass;
foreach ($a as $k => $v) {
    if (is_numeric($k)) {
        $k = "_{$k}";
    }
    $o->$k = $v;
}
```

EDIT: Just did one more quick test on this hypothesis, and yes, they officially "do not exist" in object context; the data is stored, but it's impossible to access, and is therefore the ultimate private member.  Here is the test:

```
$a = array('one','two','three');
$o = (object)$a;
var_dump(property_exists($o, 1), property_exists($o, '1'));
```

And the output is:

```
bool(false)
bool(false)
```

EDIT AGAIN: Interesting side-note, the following operation comes back false:

```
$a = array('one','two','three','banana' => 'lime');
$b = array('one','two','banana' => 'lime');

$y = (object)$a;
$z = (object)$b;

var_dump($y == $z);
```

Comment: This _is_ actually [a bug](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=45959). It has been deemed as "too expensive to fix" and the resolution has been "updated the documentation to describe this useless quirk, so it is now officially correct behavior".

Answer (score 7):

It appears that the ArrayObject class can access the properties

```
$a = new ArrayObject($obj);
echo $a[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

> Yes, they are just locked away unless cast back to an array.

Maybe, the properties are still there and are accessible, just not directly. However, I'm not sure how foreach works internally (it might cast the object to an array) as I have not dived in the source code.

Example:

```
$array = array('one', 'two', 'three', 'four');
$obj = (object) $array;

foreach ($obj as $key => &$val) {
    print "$key -> $val<br>";
    $val = 'Nhaca';
    var_dump($obj);
}
print_r($obj);
print_r($array);
```

output:

```
0 -> one
object(stdClass)[1]
  &string 'Nhaca' (length=5)
  string 'two' (length=3)
  string 'three' (length=5)
  string 'four' (length=4)
1 -> two
object(stdClass)[1]
  string 'Nhaca' (length=5)
  &string 'Nhaca' (length=5)
  string 'three' (length=5)
  string 'four' (length=4)
2 -> three
object(stdClass)[1]
  string 'Nhaca' (length=5)
  string 'Nhaca' (length=5)
  &string 'Nhaca' (length=5)
  string 'four' (length=4)
3 -> four
object(stdClass)[1]
  string 'Nhaca' (length=5)
  string 'Nhaca' (length=5)
  string 'Nhaca' (length=5)
  &string 'Nhaca' (length=5)
stdClass Object ( [0] => Nhaca [1] => Nhaca [2] => Nhaca [3] => Nhaca ) 
Array ( [0] => one [1] => two [2] => three [3] => four )
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you get an error because casting an integer key of an array to an object / subobject will break the naming conventions of PHP varibles.

Tips:

- Decide before hands whether you want to have an `OBJECT` or an `ARRAY`
- Be careful with type casting (e.g. (object) array(1=>'string') do not do such things)
- Use castings for validation and not to convert things
- Avoid using objects as "fake" arrays