# can i use stdClass like an array?

Tags: php, arrays, stdclass

is it possible to make stdClass objects work like a generically indexed array?

i.e.
$array = Array
(
[0] => 120
[1] => 382
[2] => 552
[3] => 595
[4] => 616
)

would be constructed like

```
$a = array();
$array[] = 120;
$array[] = 382;
```

etc.

but if i do that with an object it just overwrites itself:

```
$obj = new stdClass;
$obj->a = 120;
$obj->a = 382;
```

i know i can change 'a' every time,

sorry if this is a stupid question but it's stumping me for some reason!

Appreciate any help :)

Dan

Comment: You just want to push a field onto an object?  That doesn't make sense.  Use an array.

Comment: It sounds like the original poster wants an object that you can assign properties to, but alson has a built in array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In short, no, because you will always have to name your properties.  Going through the trouble of writing a simple class with ArrayAccess makes no sense either as you've essentially recreated an array with nothing to show for it except extreme sacrifices in performance and transparency.

Is there some reason your problem cannot be solved infinitely more simply by using an array, or is this just a wish-I-knew question?

EDIT: Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1869812/casing-an-array-with-numeric-keys-as-an-object) for more info.

Comment: i think that might be it. 

it is kind of a wish i knew question: i know i could use an array, but for me, using just stdClass objects is neater than using arrays and stdClass objects for the instance where i want to use objects within arrays.

Answer (score 4):

No, you can't. Using the brackets (`[]`) like that is called "ArrayAccess" in PHP, and is not implemented on the `stdClass` object.

It sounds like you **might** want something like

```
$foo = new stdClass();
$foo->items = array();
$foo->items[] = 'abc';
$foo->items[] = '123';
$foo->items[] = 'you and me';
```

You could also try casting an array as a stdClass to see what happens.

```
$foo = array();
$foo[] = 'abc';
$foo[] = '123';
$foo[] = 'you and me';
$foo = (object) $foo;
var_dump($foo);
```

Comment: This happens: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1869812/casing-an-array-with-numeric-keys-as-an-object

Comment: I know, look at who asked that question.

Comment: look at who answered it.

Answer (score 1):

I can't really see what you mean to do, short of

```
<?php
$obj->a = array();
$obj->a[] = 120;
$obj->a[] = 382;
// ...
?>
```

You cannot simply "push" a field onto an object.  You need to know the name of the field in order to retrieve the value anyways, so it's pretty much nonsense.

Answer (score 1):

An object is not an array. If you want numerically indexed elements, use an array.

If you want named elements use either an Object or an Associative Array.

As for why you're getting different behaviour, it's because in the Array, you are not specifying an index, so PHP uses the length of the Array as the index. With the Object, you have to specify the name (in this case 'a').

The other thing you may want to do is have an Object, with a member that is an array:

```
$obj = new stdClass;
$obj->arr = array();
$obj->arr[] = 'foo';
$obj->arr[] = 'bar';
```

also don't forget you can cast an array to an object:

```
$obj = (object) array(
    'arr' => array(
        'foo',
        'bar'
    )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Only for the sake of OOP, don't use classes. If you really want to implement this functionality, use this class:

```
class ArrayClass
{
    protected $storage = array();

    public function push($content) {
        $this->storage[] = $content;
        return $this;
    }

    public function get($index) {
        if (isset($this->storage[$index])) {
            return $this->storage[$index];
        } else {
            //throw an error or
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd suggest using array_key_exists instead of isset, as isset will return false if the value is null.

Answer (score -1):

You can get exactly this in JavaScript.