# Replace the value of a specific key in a flat array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array in PHP which looks like that:

```
$test = array('3' => 5);
```

How could I replace the stringed array key 3?
I tried:

```
$test['3'] = "New value"
```

but it don't work, it look like that after that:

```
array('3' => 5, 3 => "New value")
```

PHP version: 5.2.11

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most possible way you can get the numerical index represented by string is when you convert object with numeric property name to array.

More detailed this covered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1869812/casing-an-array-with-numeric-keys-as-an-object)

Comment: Okay, I casted the "source array" to an object, now it works!

Answer (score 4):

Works great for me

```
$ php -r '$foo = array("3" => 5); $foo["3"] = 6; print_r($foo);'
Array
(
    [3] => 6
)
```

Comment: $ php -v
PHP 5.3.1 (cli) (built: Feb 11 2010 02:32:22) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2009 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2009 Zend Technologies

Comment: and on another machine:
$ php -v
PHP 5.2.11 with Suhosin-Patch 0.9.7 (cli) (built: Dec 11 2009 16:30:44) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2009 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2009 Zend Technologies

Comment: works here even on my old mac internal php version.
PHP 5.2.11 (cli) (built: Dec 14 2009 19:23:40) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2009 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2009 Zend Technologies

Comment: Works on 5.3.1 on Windows XP too

Answer (score 2):

The first is actually creating a numerically indexed array key, the second a string key.  You can use [type casting](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php#language.types.typecasting) to force consistent behavior.

```
$test = array((string) '3' => 5);
$test[(string) '3'] = "New value";
```

Update, these behave identically for me on PHP Version 5.2.13:

```
$test = array('3' => 5);
echo '<pre>'.print_r($test,true).'</pre>';
$test['3'] = "New value";
echo '<pre>'.print_r($test,true).'</pre>';

$test = array((string) '3' => 5);
echo '<pre>'.print_r($test,true).'</pre>';
$test[(string) '3'] = "New value";
echo '<pre>'.print_r($test,true).'</pre>';
```

Comment: casting string to string? ;-)

Comment: this might be a silly question, but isn't `'3'` already a string?

Comment: @nickf - it absolutely is. And my mind is going round in circles with this question. What could it possibly mean? my best guess is the code in the question is *not* what was tested.

Comment: Normally I expect people to leave a comment when they downvote an answer, but for this one, I'm left pondering why you'd upvote it? All that it says is a string is the same after you cast it to a string.

Comment: I was assuming that he had a variable that had the value of '3' in it, and was getting odd behavior for that reason. The accepted answer is a much different situation. I wish the OP had given a better code example. I don't know who voted me up.

Comment: Normally I expect people to vote to close questions that cannot be reproduced.

Comment: @mickmackusa Stack Overflow was a bit more "wild" thirteen years ago

Comment: No disagreement there.  This page is currently seeking 2 more close votes.  It is never too late to curate better content.