# How to serialize large objects/arrays to JSON

Tags: php, arrays, json, zend-framework, spl

My app needs to produce json of an object that has a large `data` property of type array. The array needs to remain in memory as it collects DB output and some properties can only be determined once the array is completed.

Complication: the array is numerically-based and must appear as such in the json output, therefore straight `json_encode()` is not an option.

To make this possible on low-spec machines like RasPi I've looked into trimming memory consumption:

1. Use `SPLFixedArray`
2. Use `string` and `pack()`

Both approaches take care of the array storage memory problem but fail when it comes to encoding in JSON.

I've looked into implementing `JsonSerializable` but as it forces users to return the result which is then encoded in Json I'm back to

```
public function jsonSerialize() {
    return $this->toArray();
}
```

which has the same memory problems.

`zendframework/Component_ZendJson` looks promising as it looks for objects having a `toJson()` method to provide their own encoding as `string`instead of `object`.

I'm wondering if there are better options that don't give memory issues?

Comment: I am sure that what you are doing is way above my head but PHP natively has **[json_encode](http://us2.php.net/json_encode)**. If it doesn't apply then I can delete this comment =)

Comment: Good catch. There is a reason of course that I forgot to mention. Bummer. Complication: the array is numerically-based and must appear as such in the json output, therefore straight `json_encode()` is not an option.

Comment: This? http://stackoverflow.com/a/4844309/46675

Comment: @MikeB: need the other way round- force it to array instead of object.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In my investigation I've looked at 5 different approaches for storing large arrays of tuples in memory, summarized here with their results (sampled at 50k records):

1. *Naive*

   Exporting json is straightforward with json_encode using `array(array(), array())`

   Memory: 18.5MB (**huge**)
   Time: ~100ms to build and dump the array (Windows PC)
2. *SPL Library*

   This approach stores everything in nested `SPLFixedArrays`: `SPLFixedArray[SPLFixedArray]`. JSON export was done extending `Zend\Json\Encoder` by implementing the `toJson` method.

   Memory: 15.5MB (**still large**)
   Time: ~1.3s, x10 slower
3. SPL Library

   Similar to 2, but instead of the inner `SPLFixedArray` uses packed strings from PHP's `pack()` function.

   Memory: 3.5MB (**5 times smaller**)
   Time: ~1.3s, x10 slower - apparently `pack()` is similarly slow as nested array.
4. SPL Library

   Similar to 2, but instead of the inner `SPLFixedArray` the actual Tuples are simply written as sequential values to the root array.

   Memory: 3.25MB (**again smaller**)
   Time: ~0.7s, only x6 slower - do we have a winner here?
5. `pack()`

   Similar to 3, but instead of the root `SPLFixedArray` pack everything into a single string using PHP's `pack()` function. This does obviously need knowledge about and a fixed, identical structure of the individual arrays.

   Memory: 1.25MB (**really small - only 1/12th of original memory**)
   Time: ~1.7s, x16 slower

**CONCLUSION**

While (5) offers best memory utilization it is also extremely slow. For my purposes I've settled on (4) which is about 20% of original memory consumption but- when JSON encoding is taken into account- also 5~6 times slower. An acceptable compromise.

Comment: one of the best and most comprehensive answers possible.

Answer (score -1):

According to [json.org](http://www.json.org):

> JSON is built on two structures:
>
> - **A collection of name/value pairs**. In various languages, this is realized as an **object**, record, struct, dictionary, hash table, keyed
>     list, or associative array.
> - **An ordered list of values**. In most languages, this is realized as an **array**, vector, list, or sequence.

---

I don't know if there are memory issues with this but consider the following code:

```
<?php
// No declared index causes no index in JSON
$arr = array('dssdf','38904uj');
echo json_encode($arr).'<br><br>';
// ["dssdf","38904uj"]

// start array at 0 removes the index from JSON
$arr = array('0'=>'dssdf','1'=>'38904uj');
echo json_encode($arr).'<br><br>';
// ["dssdf","38904uj"]

// start array at 1 forces the index to show in JSON
$arr = array('1'=>'dssdf','2'=>'38904uj');
echo json_encode($arr).'<br><br>';
// {"1":"dssdf","2":"38904uj"}

// skip an index forces the index to show in JSON
$arr = array('0'=>'dssdf','1'=>'38904uj','3'=>'321as5d4');
echo json_encode($arr).'<br><br>';
// {"0":"dssdf","1":"38904uj","3":"321as5d4"}

// JSON_FORCE_OBJECT option forces indexes
$arr = array('0'=>'dssdf','1'=>'38904uj');
echo json_encode($arr, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT).'<br><br>';
// {"0":"dssdf","1":"38904uj"}
?>
```