# How to encode large amount of data as json

Tags: php, json, mysqli

I need to be able to pass a json from php to the client so javascript can parse the code and return it. Currently, the way I have always done this is:

```
<?php
    $mysql_query = $mysqli->query(QUERY GOES HERE);
    $array - array();
    while($row = $mysql_query->fetch_assoc()){
        array_push($array, $row);
    }
    $json =json_encode($array);
?>
<!-- javascript -->
<script>
    var json = <?php echo $json;?>;
    //...
</script>
<!--- rest of html --->
```

This usually works. However, the query returns more than 100,000 rows, and php is currently running out of memory on creating the entire array. I have seen some people say to use ajax. Is this the only way? And if so, how exactly would I go about implementing it? Or is there a more efficient method of encoding the mysql data into json without ajax?

Thank you

Comment: its a webservice or you want to show on your website?

Comment: I dont know why you need millions of rows at once , but you can do that by making chunks of your query using offset or defining for loop limit, and store them in different arrays. Really not a good practice.

Comment: 100K of rows is rather big. PHP arrays consume lots of memory in themselves and probably the rows are getting bigger. If you _have_ to send them always, consider [SPL](http://php.net/manual/en/class.splfixedarray.php)

Comment: @ahmed essentially im analyzing data. Users submit to the database, and I specify the date range, and I want to see the data for the various users.

Comment: @anwerjunaid I need to analyze data based on differing days, and based on the range, it can be from a couple hundred to thousands. (This specific example spans a few months). I was thinking that I need to send it in chunks as well, but how exactly would I implement it so javascript can access them normally? Another solution I was thinking was writing the information into an xml file, and then using json to parse it. Does this seem like a plausable solution, or rather, better solution?

Comment: @vlzvl It seems that while SPL may make arrays faster, it does not solve the out of memory issue.

Comment: @user3855005, in fact it's the other way around. SPL arrays are going to be slower, but memory usage will be smaller, far smaller in some cases, which is probably the #1 issue for you right now. Check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21021283/how-to-serialize-large-objects-arrays-to-json) also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you said you can also *send your array in chunks*, meaning you can process your data while it's sorted out in several ways, i consider doing this:

- *Fetch* the database data in small chunks (memory wise), in normal php arrays. 
  Doing it such a way that you `unset` the previously allocated chunk to free memory.
- JSON encode your partial data into an HTML element.

*Like this:*

```
<input id="json-1" type="hidden" data-json='<?php echo json_encode($chunk[0]); ?>' />
<input id="json-2" type="hidden" data-json='<?php echo json_encode($chunk[1]); ?>' />
<input id="json-3" type="hidden" data-json='<?php echo json_encode($chunk[2]); ?>' />
```

Yes, it *looks ugly* but consider some pros:

- There's no giant javascript JSON object, hogging the client's memory
- You can parse the data in a progressive way, thus consuming only a portion of memory

*javascript processing*

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $("input[id^='json-']").each(function() {
       var json = $(this).data("json");

       // process the chunkied 'json'

       // remove the memory allocated (since you dont want anymore the huge data, probably)
       $(this).removeData(this,"json")
    });
 });
```

Comment: I did not get a chance until now to try this out. Now the server no longer crashes. Thank you for your method!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass something from `php` to `javascript` you will have to use `ajax` as `php` is server side and `javascript` is client side.

Having an array of 100,000 rows is a bit big and could cause problems. Consider splitting the array into smaller chunks or limiting the query.

You can increase `php`s memory limit but it would be better to optimize the array first.

Answer (score -2):

You don't need to handle so large amount of data.
Separate into pages.