# json array response for PHP web service

Tags: php, mysql, json

In this service I am getting output but I want different output.
Let me explain:

```
    $customer_id = $_POST['customer_id'];
    $response = array();
    $qry="SELECT category FROM nesbaty_customer where c_id='".$customer_id."' ";
    $qry_res=mysqli_query($con,$qry);
    $jsonData = array();
    while ($array = mysqli_fetch_assoc($qry_res)) 
    {
        $r= $array['category'];

        $jsonData[]=explode(",",$r);

    }
    echo json_encode(array('data' =>$jsonData));
    mysqli_close($con);
```

I am getting Output like this:

```
{
"data": {
    "category": [
        "Hotel",
        "Saloon"
    ]
}
```

}

But I want output like this!

```
{"data":[{"category":"Hotel"},{"category":"Saloon"}]}
```

Comment: As you wrote it down, it has duplicated key category, so you cant get it

Comment: category is my db table field name

Comment: Here it is key for two elements of one same array

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4844223/how-do-i-json-encode-keys-from-php-array?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: **Danger**: You are **vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/)** that you need to [defend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) yourself from.

Comment: @Eakethet  yes@Eakethet  yes@Eakethet  yes@Eakethet  yes

Comment: @JayvirsinhVaghela you cant have 2 same keys in one arrrrray, argh, try google, its quite useful tool...

Comment: NO key is ony one (Category)
but category have multiple data and i want to explode that data seaprately @Eakethet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't get exactly what you want because you would have an array with two identical keys. You can get something similar by changing:

```
$r= $array['category'];
$jsonData[]=explode(",",$r);
```

to

```
foreach (explode(',', $array['category']) as $cat) {
    $jsonData[]=array('category' => $cat);
}
```

`$jsonData` will look like this:

```
Array
(
    [data] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [category] => Hotel
                )
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [category] => Saloon
                )
        )
)
```

and the output from `json_encode` will be:

```
{"data":[{"category":"Hotel"},{"category":"Saloon"}]}
```

Comment: {
    "data": {
        "category": [
            "Hotel",
            "Saloon"
        ]
    }
}

Comment: this is my output

Comment: BUT i want This
{"data":[{"category":"Hotel"},{"category":"Saloon"}]}

Comment: But that is the output of this code... are you sure you copied it correctly?

Comment: again tell me above two line will replace by your code?

Comment: after applying your code i got this
{"data":[{"category":"Hotel,Saloon"}]}
because i have imploded this two things in one column!!

Comment: Are you saying that the value of `category` in the table is `"Hotel, Saloon"`?

Comment: OK... I misunderstood what was in the table. I thought you had two rows, one with 'Hotel' and one with 'Saloon'. I'll edit the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The keys should be unique, you shouldn't repeat "category" as a key.

"An object whose names are all unique is interoperable in the sense
that all software implementations receiving that object will agree on
the name-value mappings.  When the names within an object are not
unique, the behavior of software that receives such an object is
unpredictable."

See https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7159 for JSON definition.

As you can see, [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) uses this rfc:
"PHP implements a superset of JSON as specified in the original » RFC 7159. "

If you really want to write non-unique keys, you should write your custom json encode function, but the decode function will have unpredictable behaviour.

Comment: brother firstly understand my query!
multiple data imploded in single row  and want to explode all that data like this
{"data":[{"category":"Hotel"},{"category":"Saloon"}]}

Comment: We are not speaking about the database key, but about the JavaScript Object keys. You are trying to use the same key "category" two times inside this object.data

Answer (score 0):

Add each category as separate json object then:

```
while ($array = mysqli_fetch_assoc($qry_res)) {
    foreach ($array['category'] as $categoryName) {
        $jsonData[] = ['category' => $categoryName];
    }
}
```

This way you end up with an array of objects, thus you should be fine.

Answer (score -1):

The key of the array must be unique

Answer (score -2):

while ($array = mysqli_fetch_assoc($qry_res)) 
    {

```
    $jsonData[]=$array;

}
echo json_encode(array('data' =>$jsonData));
```

Comment: oh men ! i want to explode two category it will return in one!!