# Converting array to json data in PHP

Tags: php, json, key

when I print the array I created with php to the screen with the *print_r* function, it looks normal.

But when I convert it to json data with the *json_encode* function, the keys are lost.
I tried a lot but couldn't find a solution.

Thank you in advance for your help.
function -> print_r

```html
 [1] => Array
        (
            [succes] => 1
            [title] => Test Title
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => car
                    [1] => bus
                    [2] => a
                    [3] => b
                    [4] => c
                    [5] => d
                )

        )
```

Json function -> json_encode

```html
{
"0": [
  "car",
  "bus",
  "a",
  "b",
  "c",
  "d"
],
“succes”: "1",
“Title”: “Test Title”
  }
```

Comment: JSON is key value oriented. So you should make `[0] => Array` something like `'data' => Array`.

Comment: json_encode works as expected. You need to understand the difference between numeric arrays and associative arrays.

Comment: Solution: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4844223/how-do-i-json-encode-keys-from-php-array)