# cant access array in object

Tags: php

```
var_dump($img->files);

object(stdClass)#17 (6) {
  ["960"]=  string(46) "/imgs/14c99db10ee9cc28bfa7db16e961fd65-960.jpg"
  ["60"]=   string(45) "/imgs/14c99db10ee9cc28bfa7db16e961fd65-60.jpg"
  ["100"]=  string(46) "/imgs/14c99db10ee9cc28bfa7db16e961fd65-100.jpg"
  ["200"]=  string(46) "/imgs/14c99db10ee9cc28bfa7db16e961fd65-200.jpg"
  ["300"]=  string(46) "/imgs/14c99db10ee9cc28bfa7db16e961fd65-300.jpg"
  ["500"]=  string(46) "/imgs/14c99db10ee9cc28bfa7db16e961fd65-500.jpg"
}
```

how can use one index

```
var_dump($img->files["60"]);
```

Fails

Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

Comment: Have you tried $img->files->{"60"} ? (forgive me if the syntax is slightly off, been a while for PHP

Comment: possible duplicate of [Casting an array with numeric keys as an object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1869812/casting-an-array-with-numeric-keys-as-an-object?rq=1)

Comment: Note to voters for "this is not a real question": this _is_ a real question. It is a very unexpected and undocumented flaw in PHP. It _is_ a duplicate question though.

Comment: Yes, surely a duplicate. But I agree that this is THE gotcha of PHP.

Comment: Crap. This should actually be closed as a duplicate, not as "not a real question".

Comment: Voted for duplicate, was outnumbered, but fought bravely, may I say. )

Comment: Ah, turned out this is actually one of those "[fixed, now documentation notes the buggy behavior and it is officially the correct behavior](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=45959)" bugs in the tracker.

Answer (score 2):

It says right there in your var_dump that `$img->files` is not an array, it is an object of class `stdClass`.

You should access it using object syntax.

```
$img->files->{'60'};
```

Comment: Yes, I did. I don't have the code that generates his $img object or his $img->files object. But i generated some objects like that myself and it worked by accessing via the arrow operator.

Comment: Also tried it and got `Undefined property: stdClass::$60`, seems like one of PHP's unexplained weidnesses.

Comment: Of course. ) You cannot access a numeric property directly.

Comment: And I really wonder who upvoted this. )

Comment: http://codepad.viper-7.com/Z7qUez

Comment: Oh yes you can, _only if_ you assign them as numeric properties (`$obj->{'60'} = 'foo'` then `print $obj->{'60'}` is perfectly fine)

Comment: Seems like one of those "features" that everybody sees as a bug, that get the "thank you for your report but this is not a bug" in the PHP bugtracker.

Comment: What version of PHP are you guys using perhaps the behaviour is different across versions.

Comment: I tested again by generating the `$img->files` via your suggested approach @raina77ow and I got the `ndefined property: stdClass::$60` notice, you're right. This should be a bug.

Comment: Doesn't matter, your answer is still considered to be correct by SO community. )))

Comment: But forget it, I totally understand the reasons. ) In fact, I've done something like this post when answering my first question about this PHP gotcha. So it's ok. )

Comment: Well we're both right depending on the manner in which the object is procured. For example using direct assignment `$obj->$name = 'value';` can still produce my first attempt if $name is (int) and this happens often in ArrayAccess implementations.

Answer (score 1):

That's how we can get the data structure similar to what you got:

```
$img = new stdClass();
$img->files = array(960 => "/imgs/14c99db10ee9cc28bfa7db16e961fd65-960.jpg");
$img->files = (object)$img->files;
```

... then this:

```
var_dump($img->files->{'960'}); // NULL
```

... will just print NULL. But this...

```
$img->files = (array)$img->files;
var_dump($img->files[960]);
```

... will work. ) You need to cast an array-like object (which was obviously casted to object by some external code by error) back to array. Then just access its elements as usual.

[Fiddle](http://codepad.org/XH7IFtTY) to play with.

UPDATE: ... and here's a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1869971/1229023) to the post which explains the reason of this behavior much better than I'll ever be able to. )

Answer (score 0):

PHP 5.3.10, running this test:

```
$obj = (object)array(10 => 'foo');
$obj->{20} = 'bar';

var_dump($obj);

print($obj->{10}."\n");
print($obj->{20}."\n");
```

Running it I get this result:

```
object(stdClass)#1 (2) {
  [10]=>
  string(3) "foo"
  ["20"]=>
  string(3) "bar"
}
PHP Notice:  Undefined property: stdClass::$10 in /home/lanzz/tmp/test.php on line 8

bar
```

So, numeric properties cast from array get assigned to actual *integer* properties in the object which are inaccessible, while numeric properties assigned to the object get string properties, which are accessible.

I vote it's just another bug in PHP.

Comment: I'd like that abbreviated, like YAPHPB. )