# Converting to object an indexed array

Tags: php, casting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Casting an Array with Numeric Keys as an Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1869812/casting-an-array-with-numeric-keys-as-an-object)

I was wondering about `(object)` type casting.

It's possible to do a lot of useful things, like converting an associative array to an object, and some not so useful and a bit funny (*IMHO*) things, like [converting a scalar value to object](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.object.php).

But how can I access the result of casting of an indexed array?

```
// Converting to object an indexed array
$obj = (object) array( 'apple', 'fruit' );
```

How about accessing a specific value?

```
print $obj[0];      // Fatal error & doesn't have and any sense
print $obj->scalar[0];  // Any sense
print $obj->0;      // Syntax error
print $obj->${'0'};     // Fatal error: empty property.   
print_r( get_object_vars( $obj ) ); // Returns Array()

print_r( $obj );    /* Returns
                    stdClass Object
                     (
                            [0] => apple
                            [1] => fruit
                     )
                    */
```

The following works because `stdClass` implements dynamically `Countable` and `ArrayAccess`:

```
foreach( $obj as $k => $v ) {
    print $k . ' => ' . $v . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is actually a [reported bug](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=45959).

> It has been deemed as "too expensive to fix" and the resolution has
>   been "updated the documentation to describe this useless quirk, so it
>   is now officially correct behavior" [[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1869971/474376).

However, there are some **workarounds**.

As `get_object_vars` gives you nothing, only thing you can do is:

1. You can iterate on the `stdClass` using `foreach`
2. You can cast it back as array.
3. You can change cast it to object using json_decode+json_encode (this is dirty trick)

**Example 1.:**

```
$obj = (object) array( 'apple', 'fruit' );
foreach($obj as $key => $value) { ...
```

**Example 2.:**

```
$obj = (object) array( 'apple', 'fruit' );
$array = (array) $obj;
echo $array[0];
```

**Example 3.:**

```
$obj = (object) array( 'apple', 'fruit' );    
$obj = json_decode(json_encode($obj));    
echo $obj->{'0'};
var_dump(get_object_vars($obj)); // array(2) {[0]=>string(5) "apple"[1]=>string(5)"fruit"}
```

---

**This is why you shouldn't cast non-associative array as object :)**

But if you want to, do it in this way:

```
// PHP 5.3.0 and higher
$obj = json_decode(json_encode(array('apple', 'fruit'), JSON_FORCE_OBJECT));
// PHP 5 >= 5.2.0
$obj = json_decode(json_encode((Object) array('apple', 'fruit')));
```

instead of

```
$obj = (Object) array('apple','fruit');
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. I know that's dirty and I'll never cast an indexed array... but I'm curious :-) I was looking for a _clean_ way to do this, not just a workaround. After [Mattew](http://stackoverflow.com/users/259778/matthew) noticed me about duplicated question, I read the accepted answer and suggested you an edit.