# stdClass Object has strange quirk on live site but not local machine

Tags: php, object, coercion

I created a set of helper functions to make my life easier when doing database operations in php. Essentially I pass the functions an stdClass Object that they then use to either perform an operation (delete, add, etc) or retrieve information. They seem to work as intended except for the helper function that is meant to delete database entries. What is frustrating to me is that works perfectly fine on my local machine running WAMP, but when I put it live it refuses to delete the database entries.

I think I've narrowed down the issue to a strange quirk I can't explain between the output of the stdClass Object between WAMP and my live site.

PHP:

```
<?php   
        session_start();
        require_once('dbconnect.php');
        require_once('dbhelpers.php');

        $cat = $_GET['cat'];
        $id = $_GET['id'];

        //remove row from table
        $a_remove = (object) array(
            "table" => "{$cat}",
            "columns" => (object) array(
                "`id`"
            ),
            "results" => (object) array(
                    "{$id}"
            ),
            "type" => (object) array(
                "i"
            )
        );
        removeRow($a_remove);
    ?>
```

Here is the output from the response on WAMP when I run a print_r on the $a_remove object:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [table] => subjects
    [columns] => stdClass Object
        (
            [0] => `id`
        )

    [results] => stdClass Object
        (
            [0] => 36
        )

    [type] => stdClass Object
        (
            [0] => i
        )
)
```

However when I do print_r on $a_remove on my live site, I get the following:

```
stdClass Object
(
[table] => subjects
[columns] => stdClass Object
    (
        [0] => `id`
    )

[results] => stdClass Object
    (
        [0] => 36
        [0] =>
    )

[type] => stdClass Object
    (
        [0] => i
    )
)
```

There is that strange additional index in the response for "result". Any ideas on what might be causing this?

Comment: Have you compared permissions?

Comment: Same PHP versions?

Comment: @wallyk full permissions as far as I tell

Comment: @Darren 
WAMP php version: PHP 7.2.10
Web php version: PHP 7.0.32

Comment: Version doesn't seem to matter. [No version seems to duplicate this](https://3v4l.org/Q10VO)

Comment: I run wamp and did a few tests and output is expected, uploaded to my live server and can't seem to duplicate this. Does $_GET['id'] output as expected on live?

Comment: To be perfectly honest, I think this is [another object coercion gotcha](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1869812/casting-an-array-with-numeric-keys-as-an-object). In all seriousness, you should avoid `(object)[]` coercion at all costs because it can cause unexpected results like this

Comment: @Second2None $_GET['id'] works as expected in both

Comment: @Machavity Interesting link! I'll try a workaround and see if that fixes the issue

Comment: If anyone ever encounters this issue, I seem to have fixed it by upgrading to php 7.2.