# Getting data from post array in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Ok, so I have a form that is sending me arrays in the POST array.  I am trying to read it like so:

```
$day = $this->input->post("days")[0];
```

This does not work.  PHP says "unexpected '['".  Why does this not work?

I fixed it by doing it this way:

```
$days = $this->input->post("days");
$day = $days[0];
```

I fixed my problem, I'm just curious as to why the 1st way didn't work.

Comment: Here's some SO discussion on the topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/742764/php-syntax-for-dereferencing-function-result

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Array derefencing from function calls isn't supported by PHP. It's implemented in the SVN trunk version of PHP, so it will likely make it into future versions of PHP. For now you'll have to resort to what you're doing now. For enumerated arrays you can also use `list`:

```
list($day) = $this->input->post("days");
```

See: http://php.net/list

Comment: In addition to this answer, Please check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/22652521/567854 also in case the array is an **`associative array`** :)

Comment: Since PHP 5.4, array derefencing is supported. The following will work:
`$day = $this->input->post("days")[0];`

Answer (score 8):

Syntax like this:

```
$day = $this->input->post("days")[0];
```

isn't supported in PHP. You should be doing what you are doing:

```
$days = $this->input->post("days");
$day = $days[0];
```

Answer (score 7):

Another approach could be to iterate through the array by using `foreach` like so:

```
foreach($this->input->post("days") as $day){
    echo $day;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to [Daniel Egeberg](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3112704/567854)'s answer :

Please note that **`list()`** only works with **numerical arrays**. If you/anyone want to read an **associative** array like,

```
$_POST['date'] = array
                 (
                    'day'   => 12
                    'month' => 7
                    'year'  => 1986
                 )
```

use **`extract()`** function on above array as,

```
extract($this->input->post("date"), EXTR_PREFIX_ALL, "date");
```

Now the following variables will be available to use as,

```
$date_day = 19, $date_month = 7 and $date_year = 1986
```

> **NOTE:** in the above function, first argument is the post array, second one is to protect from variable collisions and the third is the
>   prefix.

For more on **`extract()`**, refer [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php).

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score -1):

I would always do like this..

```
for($i=0; $i<count($this->input->post("days")); $i++)
{
  $day[$i] = $this->input->post("days[".$i."]");
}
```

This would be helpful if you need to interact with the db by checking each values passed by your view as an array. Otherwise I prefer foreach loop.

Cheers..

Comment: `$this->input->post("days[".$i."]")` does not work the way you think it does.