# Codeigniter multiple checkbox issue

Tags: php, codeigniter

Im using codeigniter and I have a very simple form, which has a few checkboxes:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="user_assign[]" value="' . $row->user_id . '">
```

Now, the values are definately getting posted because I can see them through firebug.

```
user_assign[]100002
user_assign[]100003
course_name Asbestos
```

But the below is empty? and i just dont understand?

```
$user_assign = $this->input->post('user_assign');
```

How is this possible?

Controller (which is damn messy because I've tried 1001 things)

```
    function update_course_assignment_org() {

    $data = $this->input->post('user_assign');

    $this->load->model('courses_model');
    $this->load->model('assignment_model');

    // get course id from posted course name
    $course_name = $this->input->post('course_name');
    $course_object = $this->courses_model->get_course_id($course_name);
    $course_id = $course_object[0]->course_id;

    //$user_assign = substr(implode(', ', $this->input->post('user_assign')), 0);


    //foreach ($this->input->post('user_assign') as $key => $value) {
        $test_obj = array(
           'course' => $data,
           'users' => $course_id,
           'org' => $this->input->post('course_name')
        ); 
    //}     

    //$this->assignment_model->save_org_assignments($user_ids);

    $this->template->write('title', 'Assignments');
    $this->template->write('navigation_strip', $this->load->view('navigation', array(), TRUE));         
    $this->template->write('content', $this->load->view('/assignments/assign_test', $test_obj, TRUE));

    $this->template->render();      


}
```

View (which is very basic because I've stripped everything down in order to try and get these values through)

```
                <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <?php var_dump($course); print_r($course); ?>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                <?php print_r($users); ?>
                <?php print_r($org); ?>
                </div>                  
            </div>
```

The form that contains the checkboxes

```
                        <?php echo form_open_multipart('assignments/update_course_assignment_org');?>
                        <table>
                            <tr>
                                <th>User</th>
                                <th>Assign course</th>
                            </tr>
                            <?php
                                foreach($users as $row) {                           

                                    echo '<tr>';
                                        echo '<td>' . $row->fname . ' ' . $row->sname . '</td>'; 
                                        echo '<td><input type="checkbox" name="user_assign[]" value="' . $row->user_id . '"></td>'; 
                                    echo '</tr>';

                                }
                            ?>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <input type="hidden" name="course_name" value="<?php echo $course[0]->course_name; ?>">                 
                                    <input type="submit" value="Assign" />
                                </td>
                            </tr>                               
                        </table>
                    </form>
```

Comment: try to check this 

print_r($this->input->post());

Comment: Refer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3112690/getting-data-from-post-array-in-codeigniter

Comment: please put view and controller code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so i managed to get it working via

```
$assignmen = @$_POST['user_assign'];
```

Don't ask me how or why?

Thanks everyone for your efforts in trying to solve this!

Answer (score 1):

the return post is an array , so try the following

```
$user_assign = $this->input->post('user_assign');
echo "<pre>";
print_r($user_assign);
```

Comment: This just echos <pre>

Comment: have you checked check box before submitting ?

Comment: Yes. and I can see in the post info via Firebug that the correct checkboxes etc are being posted. The data is there, but for some strange reason its not being picked up by the controller.

Comment: are you posting it via ajax ? is there any url so that i can view the working ?

Comment: Nope, not via Ajax. Yeah its only a demo system, so details ill send

Comment: can you please do a print_r($_POST);   inside that function so that we can see the entire post values

Comment: please make a  print_r($this->input->post('user_assign'))

Comment: please try print_r( $this->input->post());

Comment: @krishnakamur its empty/null/useless

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<input type="checkbox" name="user_assign[]" value="<?php echo $row['user_id'] ?>">
```

**In Controller**

```
$user_assign[] = $_POST('user_assign');
print_r($user_assign);
```

or

```
foreach ($_POST('user_assign') as $item) {
    echo $item;
}
```

Comment: This give me the following error: Fatal error: Array callback has to contain indices 0 and 1 in /home/enets/public_html/system/application/controllers/assignments.php on line 80

Comment: @frobak did you try foreach one??

Comment: Yes, tried both, both give same error: Fatal error: Array callback has to contain indices 0 and 1 in /home/enets/public_html/system/application/controllers/assignments.php on line 68

Comment: `var_dump($_POST('user_assign'))` and post answer

Comment: Fatal error: Array callback has to contain indices 0 and 1 in /home/enets/public_html/system/application/controllers/assignments.php on line 68

Answer (score 1):

Also check form's action as action='controller/update_course_assignment_org'

```
function update_course_assignment_org() {

   $this->form_validation->set_rules('user_assign','Check now','required');

   if($this->form_validation->run()){
     $data = $user_assign = implode(',',$this->input->post('user_assign') );
     print_r($_POST);
     exit;
  }
    $this->load->model('courses_model');
    $this->load->model('assignment_model');

    // get course id from posted course name
    $course_name = $this->input->post('course_name');
    $course_object = $this->courses_model->get_course_id($course_name);
    $course_id = $course_object[0]->course_id;

    //$user_assign = substr(implode(', ', $this->input->post('user_assign')), 0);


    //foreach ($this->input->post('user_assign') as $key => $value) {
        $test_obj = array(
           'course' => $data,
           'users' => $course_id,
           'org' => $this->input->post('course_name')
        ); 
    //}     

    //$this->assignment_model->save_org_assignments($user_ids);

    $this->template->write('title', 'Assignments');
    $this->template->write('navigation_strip', $this->load->view('navigation', array(), TRUE));         
    $this->template->write('content', $this->load->view('/assignments/assign_test', $test_obj, TRUE));

    $this->template->render();      


}
```

Try this...!

Comment: Tried this as you can see from the commented code in my controller. Array/object still empty?

Comment: OK, i tried the above code, the output was: Array ( [user_assign] => Array ( [0] => 100002 [1] => 100003 ) [course_name] => Slips & Trips )

Comment: I can echo/print the POST vars, i just cant get the array into the controller to use

Comment: Why cant i get the POST vars into the controller with $this->input->post('user_assign'). it just makes no sense whatsoever??????

Comment: user_assign[] declared as array. So consider that first.

Comment: Sorry, what does that mean?

Comment: In view checkbox is declared as array.

Comment: Ok? I have the array from POST. Thats fine! How do i process that data if i cant get it into the controller? I've been stuck on this for 2 days, Ive tried probably 999 different things for this. I am close to the edge!

Comment: Post your view page, Just the form...!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100038/discussion-between-blacmoon-and-frobak).