# Extracting the right part of PHP explode in one line

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP syntax for dereferencing function result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/742764/php-syntax-for-dereferencing-function-result)

Here is what I mean.  Currently I have to:

```
$str = "foo-bar";
$foo = explode("-",$str);
$foo = $foo[0];
```

What I want to do is:

```
$str = "foo-bar";
$foo = explode("-",$str)[0];
```

But it's a syntax error!  Is there another way to do it on one line?

EDIT:  Just want to make it clear I also want to be able to do

```
$str = "foo-bar-baz";
$bar = explode("-",$str)[1];
```

aswell.

Comment: Array dereferencing is not currently supported in PHP but it will be soon - https://wiki.php.net/rfc/functionarraydereferencing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Or you can do :

```
$foo = array_shift(explode("-", $str));
```

[EDIT] Since the question has changed, now is a very dirty way to do this :

```
list(,$foo) = explode("-", $str); // Add as many commas as needed to get the proper index
```

Comment: I'm assuming this will only work for first index?

Comment: Your question is quite unclear. Now you want to be able to access any index. Plus, you're just trying to find a way to do this in one line instead of two ?

Comment: Yes, I just want to know if it's possible, I don't believe it is.

Comment: list(,$foo) = explode('-', $str);
You can add as many commas to get the index you want. This example will get you [1]. This is one line, but yeah, this is dirty.

Answer (score 6):

```
list($foo) = explode('-', $str);
```

Comment: +1 for being the first to answer

Comment: Fine if you're only after the first index, but what if the required item was the second of three elements?

Comment: Yep, I'm after being able to do any index

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative:

```
$foo = current(explode("-", $str));
```

Comment: I'm assuming this will only work for first index?

Comment: Yes, it does work only for the first. It's just an alternative way. However with the [next](http://php.net/manual/en/function.next.php) function you can increment the array internal pointer and use this approach also for other elements.

Answer (score 0):

```
$foo = explode("-",$str) and $foo = $foo[0];
```

Seriously, though: There's no shorthand notation for this. You can do it in a few different ways on one line, but none as descriptive and short as the two-line solution you already have.