# php foreach, why using pass by reference of a array is fast?

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

Below is a test of php foreach loop of a big array, I thought that if the `$v` don't change, the real copy will not happen because of **copy on write**, but why it is fast when pass by reference?

**Code 1:**

```
function test1($a){
  $c = 0;
  foreach($a as $v){ if($v=='xxxxx') ++$c; }
}

function test2(&$a){
  $c = 0;
  foreach($a as $v){ if($v=='xxxxx') ++$c; }
}

$x = array_fill(0, 100000, 'xxxxx');

$begin = microtime(true);
test1($x);
$end1 = microtime(true);
test2($x);
$end2 = microtime(true);

echo $end1 - $begin . "\n";   //0.03320002555847
echo $end2 - $end1;           //0.02147388458252
```

But this time, using pass by reference is slow.

**Code 2:**

```
function test1($a){
  $cnt = count($a); $c = 0;
  for($i=0; $i<$cnt; ++$i)
    if($a[$i]=='xxxxx') ++$c;
}
function test2(&$a){
  $cnt = count($a); $c = 0;
  for($i=0; $i<$cnt; ++$i)
    if($a[$i]=='xxxxx') ++$c;
}
$x = array_fill(0, 100000, 'xxxxx');

$begin = microtime(true);
test1($x);
$end1 = microtime(true);
test2($x);
$end2 = microtime(true);

echo $end1 - $begin . "\n";   //0.024326801300049
echo $end2 - $end1;           //0.037616014480591
```

Can someone explain why passing by reference is fast in code1 but slow in code2?

**Edit:**
With Code 2, the `count($a)` makes the main difference, so the time of the loop took is almost the same.

Comment: You're not testing identical code, so why are you assuming that the results should be the same (and why are you attributing the difference to the argument passing method?)?

Comment: @Amber I don't assuming the results should be the same, I thought i don't need to use passing by reference because php is using copy on write.

Comment: How much faster/slower ?

Comment: I think the performance of test2 in Code 2 is not slow, but equal to test1.

Comment: @Karolis You can run the code and see the result.

Comment: @xdazz I wrote this comment before your edit :)

Comment: to me pass by reference in the code 2 varies, some times is faster some time not, but most times it is faster. And the difference is small. These are two results: faster: {0.15315198898315, 0.13273000717163} and slower {0.12822699546814, 0.13205099105835}

Comment: @Melsi Your result is much different from mine, what about the code 1?

Comment: In Code 1 test2 is much faster see some results: {0.24757385253906, 0.091295957565308}   {0.19345021247864, 0.078974962234497}

Comment: +1 Interesting question. Can't really understand why this happens.

Comment: Attempting to combine the tests (also, add a `do while` test): http://codepad.org/vIQGB6G7 Please correct if I'm missed something.

Comment: Added a `do while` with a `count`: http://codepad.org/EoHNQEjT

Comment: Maybe this  happens: We run code2, while executed in some point code2 gets pushed by the operation system in a waiting list so an other task is run by cpu.Since test1 and test2 **have similar execution times**, they make it possible for a probable interruption to affect the execution time.

Comment: And on Ideone: https://ideone.com/5g1DH

Comment: @JaredFarrish: https://ideone.com/AUGX3 - a) fixed (you had illegal offsets, $i was not defined in some tests - and b) Just passing an ArrayIterator streamlines the results (though it's fun, naturally it renders the tests useless).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I thought that if the `$v` don't change [`foreach($a as $v)`], the real copy will not happen because of **copy on write**, but why it is fast when pass by reference?

The impact is not on `$v` but on `$a`, the huge array. You either pass it as value or as reference to the function. Inside the function it's then value (test1) or reference (test2).

You have two codes (code 1 and code 2).

**Code 1:** Is using `foreach`. With `foreach` you've got two options: iterate over a value or a reference ([Example](http://codepad.org/cnCVeZG1)). When you iterate over a value, the iteration is done on a *copy* of the value. If you iterate over a reference, no copy is done.

As you use the reference in test2, it's faster. The values do not need to be copied. But in test1, you pass the array as value, the array gets copied.

**Code 2:** Is using `for`. For does nothing actually here. In both cases. You access the variable and read value from the array. That's pretty much the same regardless if it's a reference or a copy (thanks to the *copy on write* optimization in PHP).

You might now wonder, why there *is* a difference in code 2. The difference is not because of `for` but because of `count`. If you pass a reference to `count` PHP internally creates a copy of it because it `count` needs a copy, not a reference.

Read as well: [*Do not use PHP references* by Johannes Schlüter](http://schlueters.de/blog/archives/125-Do-not-use-PHP-references.html)

---

I've compiled a set of tests as well. But I more specifically put code into the test functions.

- Blank - What's the difference in calling the function?
- Count - Does `count` make a difference?
- For - What happens with `for`only (not `count`)?
- Foreach - Just `foreach` - even breaking on first element.

Every test is in two versions, one called `_copy` (passing the array as copy into the function) and one called `_ref` (passing the array as reference).

It's not always that these micro-benchmarks tell you the truth, but if you're able to isolate specific points, you can quite well do an educated guess, for example that not `for` but `count` had the impact:

```
function blank_copy($a){
}
function blank_ref(&$a){
}
function foreach_copy($a){
    foreach($a as $v) break;
}
function foreach_ref(&$a){
    foreach($a as $v) break;
}
function count_copy($a){
  $cnt = count($a);
}
function count_ref(&$a){
  $cnt = count($a);
}
function for_copy($a){
    for($i=0;$i<100000;$i++)
        $a[$i];
}
function for_ref(&$a){
    for($i=0;$i<100000;$i++)
        $a[$i];
}

$tests = array('blank_copy', 'blank_ref', 'foreach_copy', 'foreach_ref', 'count_copy', 'count_ref', 'for_copy', 'for_ref');


$x = array_fill(0, 100000, 'xxxxx');
$count = count($x);
$runs = 10;

ob_start();

for($i=0;$i<10;$i++)
{
    shuffle($tests);
    foreach($tests as $test)
    {
        $begin = microtime(true);
        for($r=0;$r<$runs;$r++)
            $test($x);
        $end = microtime(true);
        $result = $end - $begin;
        printf("* %'.-16s: %f\n", $test, $result);
    }
}

$buffer = explode("\n", ob_get_clean());
sort($buffer);
echo implode("\n", $buffer);
```

Output:

```
* blank_copy......: 0.000011
* blank_copy......: 0.000011
* blank_copy......: 0.000012
* blank_copy......: 0.000012
* blank_copy......: 0.000012
* blank_copy......: 0.000015
* blank_copy......: 0.000015
* blank_copy......: 0.000015
* blank_copy......: 0.000015
* blank_copy......: 0.000020
* blank_ref.......: 0.000012
* blank_ref.......: 0.000012
* blank_ref.......: 0.000014
* blank_ref.......: 0.000014
* blank_ref.......: 0.000014
* blank_ref.......: 0.000014
* blank_ref.......: 0.000015
* blank_ref.......: 0.000015
* blank_ref.......: 0.000015
* blank_ref.......: 0.000015
* count_copy......: 0.000020
* count_copy......: 0.000022
* count_copy......: 0.000022
* count_copy......: 0.000023
* count_copy......: 0.000024
* count_copy......: 0.000025
* count_copy......: 0.000025
* count_copy......: 0.000025
* count_copy......: 0.000026
* count_copy......: 0.000031
* count_ref.......: 0.113634
* count_ref.......: 0.114165
* count_ref.......: 0.114390
* count_ref.......: 0.114878
* count_ref.......: 0.114923
* count_ref.......: 0.115106
* count_ref.......: 0.116698
* count_ref.......: 0.118077
* count_ref.......: 0.118197
* count_ref.......: 0.123201
* for_copy........: 0.190837
* for_copy........: 0.191883
* for_copy........: 0.193080
* for_copy........: 0.194947
* for_copy........: 0.195045
* for_copy........: 0.195944
* for_copy........: 0.198314
* for_copy........: 0.198878
* for_copy........: 0.200016
* for_copy........: 0.227953
* for_ref.........: 0.191918
* for_ref.........: 0.194227
* for_ref.........: 0.195952
* for_ref.........: 0.196045
* for_ref.........: 0.197392
* for_ref.........: 0.197730
* for_ref.........: 0.201936
* for_ref.........: 0.207102
* for_ref.........: 0.208017
* for_ref.........: 0.217156
* foreach_copy....: 0.111968
* foreach_copy....: 0.113224
* foreach_copy....: 0.113574
* foreach_copy....: 0.113575
* foreach_copy....: 0.113879
* foreach_copy....: 0.113959
* foreach_copy....: 0.114194
* foreach_copy....: 0.114450
* foreach_copy....: 0.114610
* foreach_copy....: 0.118020
* foreach_ref.....: 0.000015
* foreach_ref.....: 0.000016
* foreach_ref.....: 0.000016
* foreach_ref.....: 0.000016
* foreach_ref.....: 0.000018
* foreach_ref.....: 0.000019
* foreach_ref.....: 0.000019
* foreach_ref.....: 0.000019
* foreach_ref.....: 0.000019
* foreach_ref.....: 0.000020
```

Comment: Good through tests.  I wonder if clearing the variables (by setting them to `null` so their reference counts are 0) or calling the garbage collector directly after each iteration would give more consistent results between each batch?

Comment: Well, don't try to optimize. The main point is that if you use references, you should know what you do. Passing a reference to function that can not handle references will make PHP create a copy so the data in your reference is not tainted in case the function you call changes something. The function operates on the copy then.

Comment: @hakre Yep, in code2, `count()` takes the main difference. But why a copy is created? And my question is mainly about code 1.

Comment: @hakre Just wanted to note that your statement "Copy on write is for variables only, not references" is wrong (at least in the current form). Copy on write can still occur with `is_ref=1`, but not if you mix a ref var with more than one non-ref var (and only because this is not true in this particular example copy on write doesn't apply). Additionally this doesn't explain why the foreach by ref is faster (I assume this is the main question here, as the other part is fairly straightforward.)

Comment: I missed the foreach part of the question and I know that my wording is not precise. Thanks for the clarifcation. However foreach operates on an array copy as well - as documented. Will edit the answer.

Comment: @hakre But doesn't foreach make the copy either way? You would need to *iterate* by ref for it not to make one, wouldn't you? I don't think that *passing* by ref makes much of a difference there.

Comment: @NikiC: Compare the results of test1a and test2a. test1a is as value, test2a is as reference.

Comment: @xdazz: I now updated the answer, should be better written more specifically to your question. I hope this sheds some lights, placed a link as well.

Comment: @hakre Thanks for your answer. But why foreach doesn't use copy on write and need the actual copy?

Comment: @xdazz: That's how [`foreach`](http://php.net/for_each) works. If you look into the manual it's written that `foreach` operates on a copy unless you pass a reference. It's not that it needs to copy but that it does. If you want to prevent that, pass a reference. Or you can use an iterator object (which has the overhead on instantiation, but not later on the `foreach`, e.g. if you run multiple `foreach`es). Run your tests with `$x = array_fill(0, 100000, 'xxxxx');
$x = new ArrayIterator($x);` if you want to see the fun :)

Comment: @hakre Thanks, it should be the answer:)

Comment: @hakre +1 for your foreach code example. I really misunderstood that foreach thing all the time. I though it applies only to by-ref iteration, but as your example shows this applies also to ref-ed variables. Thanks!

Comment: Another related question [Performance of FOR vs FOREACH in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3430194/367456)

Answer (score 4):

Actually, I disagree a bit with the first answer. Most importantly, as the comments say, the tests are not the same. Here's the fully-isolated tests, testing ONLY the loops.

Version 1:

```
<?php
function test1($a) {
    $c = 0;
    $begin = microtime(true);
    foreach ($a as $v) {
        if ($v == 'x') ++$c;
    }
    $end = microtime(true);
    echo $end - $begin . "\n";
    return $c;
}

function test2(&$a) {
    $c = 0;
    $begin = microtime(true);
    foreach ($a as $v) {
        if ($v == 'x') ++$c;
    }
    $end = microtime(true);
    echo $end - $begin . "\n";
    return $c;
}

$x = array_fill(0, 1000000, 'x');

test1($x); // 0.11617302894592
test2($x); // 0.059789180755615
```

Version 2:

```
<?php
function test1($a) {
    $cnt = count($a);
    $c = 0;
    $begin = microtime(true);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $cnt; ++$i) if ($a[$i] == 'x') ++$c;
    $end = microtime(true);
    echo $end - $begin . "\n";
    return $c;
}

function test2(&$a) {
    $cnt = count($a);
    $c = 0;
    $begin = microtime(true);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $cnt; ++$i) if ($a[$i] == 'x') ++$c;
    $end = microtime(true);
    echo $end - $begin . "\n";
    return $c;
}

$x = array_fill(0, 1000000, 'x');

test1($x); // 0.086347818374634
test2($x); // 0.086491107940674
```

Notice that in the fully-isolated form, the second tests show NO differences, while the first one does. Why?

The answer is that the array has an internal pointer for things like foreach. It can be accessed by calls like [current](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.current.php). When you do foreach with a reference, the original array's pointers is used. When you pass by value, the array internals must be copied as soon as the foreach executes, even if the values are maintained somehow by the engine. Thus, the penalty.

Comment: I'd like to have a source-code or other authoritative reference on the "When you pass by value, the array internals must be copied as soon as the foreach executes" part. Afaik foreach will just reset the array pointer.

Comment: Good point about creating two separate tests.  Seems the first test was in fact interferring with the results of the second ... Heisenberg anyone?