# Filtering posts from a large multi-dimentional array, PHP, Facebook API

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, iteration, facebook-php-sdk

I need help moving through the large array returned by the Facebook PHP SDK. I am trying to find all posts from the user, then also check if the post does/doesn't contain the 'link' key. I have read that it is inefficient to use the foreach loop on arrays of this size due to the copying of the 1MB+ of data to process it. How should I traverse through the information effectively?

The array is structured like this, where 'x' is the number of each post:

```
Array
(
    [data] => Array
        (
            [x] => Array
                (
                    [from] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => james
                        )

                    [message] => Thanks for the great interview! 
                    [link] => http://example.com/link.html
                    [description] => Description here
                    [etc] => Various other keys possible
                )
        )
)
```

Then my current code looks like this where $feed is the array from the Facebook API:

```
for ($x=0, $y=0; $x<=1000, $y<=19; $x++) {

    if (array_key_exists('james', $feed['data'][$x]['from']['name'])) {

        if (!array_key_exists('link', $feed['data'][$x])) {

            echo "<div>" . $feed['data'][$x]['message'] . "<hr>" . $feed['data'][$x]['description'] . "</div>";

            $y++;
        };

    };

};
```

I have read about the various iterators but I wouldn't know which to use! Hope you can help me out, cheers, Joe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Speaking about foreach performance 
and using array_key_exists in actual fact it's a non sense
imho it's far better like

```
foreach($feed['data'] as $post){
           if($post['from']['name']==='youruser'){
            //has user
           }
          if(isset($post['link'])){
            //has link
          }
}
```

put it in the cillosis way
and it should be faster.

Comment: thanks so much- yes that was just to describe my logic- I know it is very inefficient code. I am using the foreach then will use the techniques above to optimise later. Thanks again for your help! :)

Answer (score 1):

You are correct in the fact that `foreach` can be slow when iterating over large arrays because by default it uses a *copy* of the value and like you mentioned, that copying can consume memory and take a bit of a time hit.

But, another way to use foreach is *by reference* which does not create a copy. It works with the original value. This means no matter what size the array is, it won't be placed into memory again. Here is an example of a *foreach by reference* as [shared by another StackOverflow user](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7787283/468592):

```
$a = array('hello', 'world');
$asRef =& $a;
$ontime = 0;
foreach($asRef as $i => $v)
{
   if (!$ontime++) $a = array('hash', 'the cat');
   echo " $i: $v\n";
}
```

You have the option of using the [ArrayIterator](http://php.net/manual/en/class.arrayiterator.php) from the SPL which is written in C and is pretty fast. Just a quick example of how that would work:

```
// This would be your large facebook array
$big_array = array(1,2,3,...,10000,10001);

// Get the iterator object
$array_iterator = new ArrayIterator($big_array);

foreach($array_iterator as $item)
{
   //Do something with $item here
}
```

I've not done any benchmarking but I would imagine passing the array by reference and using the ArrayIterator would probably be a good solution.

Comment: Thanks so much- I will implement these techniques when I streamline my code. :)

Answer (score -1):

foreach doesn't always copy. when it does copy, it copies only the immediate data structure being iterated; it doesn't copy any values. for example, if you did

```
foreach ($arr['data'] as $k => $v) ....
```

if there were 100 sub elements (you abbreviated one as [x] ), then it would make an array, copy those 100 keys, but would not copy the values that the keys point to, the values being the sub arrays/trees. internally it just stores a pointer and has it point to the subarray's memory address, without copying.

I think you're making a big deal for nothing, as the amount of data that actually gets copied is very little. foreach is almost always very very fast...

if you want to glimpse, look at [memory_get_usage](http://www.php.net/memory_get_usage)() and [memory_get_peak_usage](http://www.php.net/memory_get_peak_usage)() before and after your loop.

Comment: surely if your site processing lots of traffic at some point it is better to have more efficient code?

Comment: of course. however, the benefit received per minute of developer time spent is probably very very low here compared to other opportunities.