# Calling PHP explode and access first element?

Tags: php, string, explode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP syntax for dereferencing function result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/742764/php-syntax-for-dereferencing-function-result)

I have a string, which looks like *1234#5678*. Now I am calling this:

```
$last = explode("#", "1234#5678")[1]
```

Its not working, there is some syntax error...but where? What I expect is 5678 in `$last`. Is this not working in PHP?

Comment: You'll be able to do this (Array Dereferencing) in PHP 5.4, not in the current 5.3

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Array dereferencing is not possible in the current PHP versions (unfortunately). But you can use [`list` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://php.net/manual/en/function.list.php) to directly assign the array elements to variables:

```
list($first, $last) = explode("#", "1234#5678");
```

**UPDATE**

Since PHP 5.4 (released 01-Mar-2012) it supports [array dereferencing](http://php.net/ChangeLog-5.php#5.4.0).

Comment: and if you have many values in string then you can use
$last = end(explode('#', $string));

Comment: Alternate for list is `list(,$last) = ....`. Then you won't have the first variable hanging when you don't need it.

Answer (score 13):

Most likely PHP is getting confused by the syntax.  Just assign the result of `explode` to an array variable and then use index on it:

```
$arr = explode("#", "1234#5678");
$last = $arr[1];
```

Comment: Wow, that sucks :D ... ok, good I know now.

Answer (score 8):

Here's how to get it down to one line:

`$last = current(array_slice(explode("#", "1234#5678"), indx,1));`

Where `indx` is the index you want in the array, in your example it was 1.

Answer (score 5):

You can't do this:

```
explode("#", "1234#5678")[1]
```

Because `explode` is a function, not an array. It returns an array, sure, but in PHP you can't treat the function as an array until it is set into an array.

This is how to do it:

```
 $last = explode('#', '1234#5678');
 $last = $last[1];
```

Answer (score 3):

PHP can be a little dim. You probably need to do this on two lines:

```
$a = explode("#", "1234#5678");
$last = $a[1];
```