# Good practice for referencing returned array values

Tags: php, arrays, function

This is something I haven't seen before but it appears to be supported and it does work, referencing the returned array key directly after the providing function is called. BUT... is this good practice? Will this be supported in the future? Does this even have a name?

```
<?php

function example_function() {
    $return = array('part_1', 'part_2');
    return $return;
}

$var = example_function()[0];

echo $var;
```

To get the same result I would normally do the following

```
$var = example_function();
$var = $var[0];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's called [Array Dereferencing](http://schlueters.de/blog/archives/138-Features-in-PHP-trunk-Array-dereferencing.html). It has been [available since PHP 5.4](http://php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php). It is acceptable to use although some might say it reduces readability.

Comment: @MikeG if you do not use it you might end http://stackoverflow.com/a/10470579/3882178

Comment: Personally, I find that it improves readability to an extent though I've found there's a few nanoseconds difference in dereferencing

Answer (score 0):

Use it only when you are sure that you will always get array to work on. Sometimes ago I've have following code in some scraper class:

```
$ip = $this->getIP()[0];
```

I didn't check whether this function could return string and it caused some logic errors. Nowadays each time when I want to get array's item I do

```
$ip = $this->getIP()

if(is_array($ip)) {
    $ip = $ip[0];
} else {
    throw new Exception('Expects array here')
}
```