# php t_array error

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP syntax for dereferencing function result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/742764/php-syntax-for-dereferencing-function-result)

i wrote some code in php 5.4 and my server can only run 5.3,thus i have some syntax errors i need to fix.

when i got to the site I get this error

```
 Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in /home/content/51/6663351/html/application/controllers/admin.php on line 247
```

line 247 is

```
if(count($results->result()) > 0)
            {
 this here>>>   $data['data'] = $results->result()[0];
                $data['cats'] = $this->db->get('category')->result();
                $data['curCat'] = $this->db->get('products_categories',     array('product_id' => $id))->result()[0];
```

so I tried changing the code to:

```
 $data = array();
 if(count($results->result()) > 0)
            {
                $data['data'] = $results->result()[0];
                $data['cats'] = $this->db->get('category')->result();
                $data['curCat'] = $this->db->get('products_categories', array('product_id' => $id))->result()[0];
```

how ever adding the $data = array(); didn't fix anything. Does anyone have an idea what is wrong?

Comment: What does `$results->result()` yield?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This `$results->result()[0]` is called array dereferencing. It's new in PHP 5.4 so you can't do it in 5.3. You'll need to return that array element first and then use it in your code.

From the manual:

```
<?php
function getArray() {
    return array(1, 2, 3);
}

// on PHP 5.4
$secondElement = getArray()[1];

// previously
$tmp = getArray();
$secondElement = $tmp[1];

// or
list(, $secondElement) = getArray();
?>
```