# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' with php 5.3

Tags: php, php-5.3, parse-error

My script is working really fine on my xampp. Now I tried to upload it on the server, but it spat directly a

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '['

in my face. :(

The line which its mocking about is this one:

```
    $item = $xml->xpath($path)[0];
```

And I have no idea what is wrong. I tried to look on the php 5.3 changelog but did not found anything about it. (Because I have 5.3 on the server, and on xampp its an olderversion)

The whole code block looks like this:

```
$path = '//item[@id="'.$id.'"]';
if ($xml->xpath($path)) {
    $item = $xml->xpath($path)[0];
} else {
    die('<p class="error">Script Error: Code 101 - Please contact administrator</p>');
}
```

I am thankful for any help, I cannot seach [ with google and have no idea where it could come from, since on xampp its working fine

Comment: you need 5.4 to use it like this. in your case `$item = $xml->xpath($path); $item[0];`

Comment: *"As of PHP 5.4 it is possible to array dereference the result of a function or method call directly. Before it was only possible using a temporary variable."* http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Comment: $item = $xml->xpath($path0); i don't know but does this work?

Comment: You need to change

    `$item = $xml->xpath($path)[0];`

to

    `$item = (string)$xml->xpath($path)[0]->value;`

Comment: I don't know why this question is duplicate of this : [PHP syntax for dereferencing function result](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/742764/php-syntax-for-dereferencing-function-result)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Try this
`$item = $xml->xpath($path);`

`$item = $item[0];`

Comment: Or you could migrate to >= PHP 5.4.x

Comment: Downvoted for promoting copypasta.