# Different Behaviour on ECS, Heroku, Local

Tags: php, postgresql, heroku, amazon-ec2

Given the line of code, `$result = pg_fetch_all(pg_query($dbconn, $query))[0];`

locally, on my MacBook, it runs just fine. On Heroku, this is also the case. On Amazon EC2, however (using Amazon Linux, not that that makes a difference), this line shows up in my logfile and it doesn't allow it: `PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '[' in /var/www/html/index.php on line ...`

Reading the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pg-fetch-all.php), `pg_fetch_all` returns a 0-based indexed array of associative arrays. So my question is, why can I not use `pg_fetch_all(whatever)[0]` or is it just a weird quirk of Amazon's system?

Answer (score 0):

The reason is you need PHP 5.4 or greater to achieve this functionality: per [Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' with php 5.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16358973/parse-error-syntax-error-unexpected-with-php-5-3)

Comment: In cases like this it is better to vote to close the question as a duplicate instead of answering it. Or if you don't have the rep for that, then leave a comment.