# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ')'

Tags: php, syntax-error, php-5.2

I have this linecode

```
$media = $dc->thumbnail->attributes()['url'];
```

runs fine on my local (WAMP) php 5.4.3
but when i host it on my server cpanel then it gives this error

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ')'
```

the php version on my server is 5.2.17

i dnt see any problem with it, please help

Comment: Because of the php version.

Comment: 5.2 and 5.4 are worlds apart my friend.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/742764/php-syntax-for-dereferencing-function-result

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You need to be running PHP 5.4+ to use shorthand arrays

Comment: $mediaArr = $dc->thumbnail->attributes();
   $media = $mediaArr->url[0]; this did it

Comment: You can call properties on a chained method in your version if you want to shorten it up: `$mediaArr = $dc->thumbnail->attributes()->url[0]`

Answer (score 0):

You can't have a php 5.4.3 and a 5.2.17 with a single WAMP installation, but from your error message, i think you are using the older one.

I guess, you are working with SimplXML. In this case, you should not use that line, anyway:

```
$media = $dc->thumbnail[0]['url'];
```

Note: `$simpleXMLElement->childrenNodeListByName`
& `$simpleXMLElement['attributeValueByName']`