# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ')' php

Tags: php, syntax-error, opencart

I am creating a custom shipping method for opencart, however i am stuck on the catalog model file, which is for `PHP 5.4+`, but how do i make it working with `PHP 5.3` as Opencart Requirement is start from PHP 5.3

**catalog/model/shipping/items.php**

```
    $languages = $this->language->get('code');
    $quote_data = array();
    $quote_data['items'] = array(
        'code'         => 'items.items',
        'title'        => $this->config->get('items_shipping_description')[$languages],
        'cost'         => $this->config->get('items_cost'),
        'tax_class_id' => $this->config->get('items_tax_class_id'),
        'text'         => $this->currency->format($this->tax->calculate($items_cost, $this->config->get('items_tax_class_id'), $this->config->get('config_tax')))
    );
```

this line working fine with PHP 5.4+ but not PHP 5.3

```
'title'=> $this->config->get('items_shipping_description')[$languages],
```

I get an error for PHP 5.3 which is

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ')' in ...
```

I've also read many duplicate question and tried many different way to make this working with no luck! please help, thank you!

Comment: *first* google hit for the *title* of the question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17411106/parse-error-syntax-error-unexpected-expecting

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP syntax for dereferencing function result](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/742764/php-syntax-for-dereferencing-function-result)

Comment: @karoly Horvath: that was the first question i've ever read, btw thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just assign it to variable:
`$description =  $this->config->get('items_shipping_description')`
And then use:

```
$quote_data['items'] = array(
    'code'         => 'items.items',
    'title'        => $description[$languages]
    'cost'         => $this->config->get('items_cost'),
    'tax_class_id' => $this->config->get('items_tax_class_id'),
    'text'         => $this->currency->format($this->tax->calculate($items_cost, $this->config->get('items_tax_class_id'), $this->config->get('config_tax')))
);
```

Comment: thanks! its working now, never thinking about doing it this way, i was just playing with the array() thing, btw did this code also can be use for PHP5.4+?

Comment: @Zulfakar Zukri, yes, it can be used.

Answer (score 1):

```
$this->config->get('items_shipping_description')[$languages]
```

This is function array dereferencing and was only added in [php 5.4](http://php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php)

To make it work with php 5.3 you will need to assign that return value to a variable and then use that.

```
$items = $this->config->get('items_shipping_description');
$items[$languages];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$desc = $this->config->get('items_shipping_description');
```

And

```
'title'        => $desc[$languages],
```