# php explode not working when using array value as string

Tags: php

I want to do `explode(" ",$q[2])[1]` where `$q[2]` is a string reading "question 1" but I keep getting errors saying that a comma or semicolon were expected instead of the right facing square bracket after the explode "`[1]`". I can use this syntax when the string isn't an array position so is there a shorthand way of doing this instead of making some temp variable and exploding it?

Comment: This will not work if your php version is < 5.4

Comment: Upgrade or $foo = explode(" ", $q[1]);$foo[1]; Consider if explode is really what you need..

Comment: Ahh, thank you. I just moved to a new hosting environment and neglected to think of the php version.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP syntax for dereferencing function result](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/742764/php-syntax-for-dereferencing-function-result)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At PHP 5.3 or under, you can't index an expression. You have to split it into two lines:

```
 x = explode(" ",$q[2]);
 y = x[1];
```

Answer (score 6):

You can try with:

```
list($first, $second) = explode(" ",$q[2]);
```

So `$second` variable is `[1]` element from the return array.

```
$first  // "question"
$second // "1"
```

It is also possible to omit `$first` variable, so:

```
list(, $second) = explode(" ",$q[2]);
```