# How to print all days between two dates

Tags: php, date

below is my php code to display all date between two dates..but not working properly...

```
fromdate = 20-04-2015
todate =   25-05-2015
```

so my code display only `20,21,22,23,24,25`

but i need all days between this two months.

**expected output**

```
20-04 21-04 22-04 23-04 24-04 25-04 26-04 27-04 28-04  ......upto 25-05
```

**below is my code..**

```
 <?php
    $startdate = $_POST['fromdate'];
    $enddate = $_POST['todate'];
    $start = date('d', strtotime($startdate));
    $end=date('d', strtotime($enddate));
    ?>  

    <?php   for ($x = $start; $x <= $end; $x++) { ?>
        <th width="58%"><?php echo $x; ?></th>
        <?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using `strtotime()` and `date()` for traversing dates is not recommended because it is hackish at best. Use `DateTime` to iterate dates instead:

```
$start    = new DateTime('20-04-2015');
$end      = (new DateTime('25-05-2015'))->modify('+1 day');
$interval = new DateInterval('P1D');
$period   = new DatePeriod($start, $interval, $end);

foreach ($period as $dt) {
    echo $dt->format("d-m") . "<br>\n";
}
```

[<kbd>**Demo**</kbd>](https://eval.in/367300)

For PHP < 5.4 (`echo phpversion();`), which doesn't support [array dereferencing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/742764):

[<kbd>**Demo**</kbd>](https://eval.in/367306)

The above code creates [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) objects for the start and end date. We have to add one day to the end date as it will not be included in our loop later on. It then creates a [`DateInterval`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php) object to represent the increment of one day and a [`DatePeriod`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateperiod.php) object to contain it all. It then loops through each date and echos out the date in the format you expect.

Comment: wow, such good explanations are sadly pretty rare on SO. *Love it!*

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_OBJECT_OPERATOR in $end      = (new DateTime('25-05-2015'))->modify('+1 day');

Comment: What version of PHP are you running?

Comment: PHP/5.3.5 version of PHP

Comment: @ankitingle See the demo in the answer for PHP versions under < 5.4, where [array dereferencing](http://stackoverflow.com/q/742764/3933332) is not supported

Comment: @JohnConde If you think my edit was too major, just do a rollback :) (Just wanted to put the references in with the manual links and example for PHP < 5.4)