# Access an Array Returned by a Function

Tags: php, arrays, function, variables, return

Is there anyway to directly access the data returned in an array without a temporary variable?

Currently, my code is as follows:

```
function getData($id) {
    // mysql query
    return mysql_fetch_array($result);
}

$data = getData($id);
echo $data['name'];
```

Is there a direct way to get the returned data without the temporary variable?

Comment: You could also wrap the function return in ```current()```,  ```key()```, ```reset()``` or ```each()``` to access the specific elements in one line.

Answer (score 11):

PHP 5.4 added array Dereferencing, here's the example from PHP's [Array documentation](http://php.net/language.types.array.php):

**Example #7 Array dereferencing**

```
function getArray() {
    return array(1, 2, 3);
}

// on PHP 5.4
$secondElement = getArray()[1];

// previously
$tmp = getArray();
$secondElement = $tmp[1];
```

Answer (score 4):

with arrays the answer is no, but you can use objects:

```
function getData($id) {
   // mysql query
   return mysql_fetch_object($result);
}

echo getData($id)->name;
```

Answer (score 3):

Not really. You could define a function to do it, though:

```
function array_value($array, $key) {
    return $array[$key];
}

// and then
echo array_value(getData($id), 'name');
```

The only other way, which probably won't help you much in this case, is to use `list()` which will get you the first `n` items in the returned array. You have to know the order of the items in the list beforehand, though:

```
function test() {
    return array(1, 2, 3, 4);
}

list($one, $two, $three) = test();
// now $one is 1, $two is 2, $three is 3
```

Answer (score 1):

I have asked a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13109/php-access-array-value-on-the-fly) some time ago.

The short answer is no, you can not. Yet, if you just need the first value in the array, you can use reset():

```
function getArray()
{
    array('la', 'li', 'lu');
}
echo reset(getArray()); // echos "la"
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, no.

You could do something like this:

```
function getData($id) {
    // mysql query
    return mysql_fetch_array($result);
}

foreach(getData("your_input_query") as $key=>$value){
   echo $value;
}
```

And then you could use a switch or if/else statements to only perform other functions on the returned data if they equal a certain value (in this case, if $key == 'name').

In short, it's much easier just to set that temporary variable and access it that way.

Answer (score 0):

I think the verbage is a little wrong for your question, but I think are looking to accomplish something like this:

```
echo getData($id)->someArrayOffset;
```

While you can do this with mysql_fetch_object, I'll show you how you can do this using ArrayObject in PHP5, or by returning your own object in PHP 4 so that you can find a usefulness for it outside of function that return objects for you. Here's your same function using ArrayObject in PHP5:

```
function getData($id) {
    // mysql query
    return new ArrayObject( mysql_fetch_array($result) );
}

echo getData($id)->name;
```