# properties as array

Tags: php, arrays

I want to do something like this without using extra variables:

```
class className {
  public static function func(){
    return array('true','val2');
  }
}

if(className::func()[0]) {
  echo 'doğru';
} else {
  echo 'Yanlış';
}
```

Comment: PHP does not support array dereferencing this way. Why can't you use an intermediate variable?

Comment: @Felix Kling PHP 5.4 will have that feature: http://css.dzone.com/polls/what-new-feature-php-54

Comment: possible duplicate of [Access an Array Returned by a Function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1664362/), [Access array returned by a function in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1459377/)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`className::func()[0]` is called *array dereferencing*, and is not valid syntax in all PHP versions.  It <strike>will be</strike> is available starting in PHP 5.4, <strike>currently in beta</strike>, released March 2012.  For earlier PHP version, you will need to use an extra variable somewhere to store the array returned from `className::func()`.

See the [PHP 5.4 Array documentation](http://docs.php.net/manual/language.types.array.php) for implementation details.

Comment: +1 for beating my by 35 seconds ;)

Answer (score 7):

Array Deferencing is not currently available in PHP. It is on the table for [PHP 5.4](http://css.dzone.com/polls/what-new-feature-php-54).

Until then, you would need the *extra* variable:

```
$arr = className::func();
if($arr[0]){
    echo 'doğru';
}else{
   echo 'Yanlış';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Well,you can return an object in your method instead.
something like:

```
class className{
      public static function func(){
          return (object)array('true'=>'true','val2'=>'val2');
      }
}

echo className::func()->true;//Extra variables go away =)
```

Answer (score 1):

As the others noted, you currently cannot do it this way. If you really cannot use an temporary variable (although I don't see a reason not to use one) you could use

```
if(current(className::func())) // or next() or reset()
```

But make sure you read the documentation about these functions to treat empty arrays properly.

**Reference**: [`current`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.current.php)

Comment: You cannot (or at least, should not) pass the result of an expression directly to `array_shift()` because it takes the input array argument by reference, since it modifies the input array. The same is true of `current()`, but to a lesser extent as I believe this does not modify the input array.

Comment: @DaveRandom: And why should this be avoided then? But you are right, `array_shift` does not work.

Comment: Because if you look at the docs, it does say that (for some reason) `current()` takes it's argument by reference. This *should* generate an `E_STRICT` as it does with `array_shift()` although I have just tried it and actually it doesn't so it may be that the docs are wrong.