# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' line 149

Tags: php, parsing, line

I have this error. Here Are my code. Can you help me please? ??? ? ?  Line 149 is the last one :(

```
    $customer_group_info = $this->model_sale_customer_group->getCustomerGroup($order_info['customer_group_id']);

    if ($customer_group_info) {
        $this->data['customer_group'] = $customer_group_info['name'];
    } else {
        $this->data['customer_group'] = '';
    }

    $this->load->model('localisation/order_status');
    $this->data['order_status'] = $this->model_localisation_order_status->getOrderStatus($order_info['order_status_id'])['name'];
```

Comment: what language is this? php?

Comment: You can't use the subscription `[]` operator on a return value (e.g. from `getOrderStatus`). You need to store it in a variable first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo can't use a function that returns an array and use it's result directly.
You have to bind the result to a variable, and then use it.

```
$temp = $this->model_localisation_order_status->getOrderStatus($order_info['order_status_id']);
$this->data['order_status'] = $temp['name'];
```

EDIT: duplicate of [Access an Array Returned by a Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1664362/access-an-array-returned-by-a-function)