# Explode and get a value in one line of code

Tags: php, arrays, explode

Can you write the following in one line of code?

```
$foo = explode(":", $foo);
$foo = $foo[0];
```

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13109/php-access-array-value-on-the-fly

Comment: [In PHP 5.4 you can!](http://php.net/migration54.new-features)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

you could use [stristr](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stristr.php) for this:

```
$foo = stristr($foo,":",true);
```

where true sets it to give you everything before the first instance of ":"

Comment: how can i get 2nd element using this ? it throws first element only.

Answer (score 7):

As an alternative to list(), you may use [array_shift()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php)

```
$foo = array_shift(explode(':', $foo));
```

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it's posible to do using [`list`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.list.php):

```
list($foo) = explode(":", $foo);
```

Comment: Thanks, that's a nice approach. However, I'd love to see an approach that doesn't require additional methods. Something like explode(":", $foo)[0];

Comment: PHP doesn't support that syntax. You're forced to do what you want to do in 2 lines.

Comment: I think PHP doesn't allow `...[0]` code unlike Python or Perl. And that's why `list` was added into language.

Answer (score 0):

Just completing @GSto answer, in case it helps:
I often have to deal with strings that can have 0 or more separators (colon in this example).

Here is a one-liner to handle such strings:

```
$first = stristr($foo,":") ? stristr($foo,":",true) : $foo;
```