# access data in return value

Tags: php

I have the line

```
if( getdate($start_time)['hours'] == 0 ){
```

and I am getting

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '['
```

But if I change the line to

```
$start_time_as_date = getdate($start_time);
if( $start_time_as_date['hours'] == 0 ){
```

I don't get an error.  Do I always have to save an array to a variable to access its data?  Or is there some way to make the first line work?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13109/php-access-array-value-on-the-fly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you do. PHP does not allow you to access an array return value in that way.

Comment: More discussion over at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13109/php-access-array-value-on-the-fly