# Can an element of an array return by a function be used without prior assignment?

Tags: php

I have a function returning an array:
`function foo(){ return array('foo'=>1,'bar'=>2); }`

Can I access an element of the return array without assigning it to a temporary variable first (e.g. `foo()['bar']`)?

The following example returning an object works like a charm:

```
function foo(){ return (object) array('foo'=>1,'bar'=>2); }
echo foo()->bar;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, unfortunately PHP's grammar doesn't allow this. There is no good reason for this btw (there are a few discussions about it on PHP mailinglists).

- [PHP: Access Array Value on the Fly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13109/298479)
- http://wiki.php.net/rfc/functionarraydereferencing [currently down - [Google Cache](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:http://wiki.php.net/rfc/functionarraydereferencing&ie=UTF-8)]

If you really want it, you could consider switching to Python - it not only supports inline access to returned arrays but also many other nice things. ;)

Comment: @prodigitalson: I have PHP 5.3.3-7 and it doesn't work either.

Comment: If I had a choice, I'd use C++, Scala, Python, JavaScript (?) etc., they not only support inline acces to returned arrays but also many other nice things...