# Getting element from PHP array returned by function

Tags: php

I'm not sure if this is possible, but I can't figure out how to do it if it is...

I want to get a specific element out of an array that is returned by a function, without first passing it into an array... like this...

```
$item = getSomeArray()[1];


function getSomeArray(){
     $ret = Array();
     $ret[0] = 0;
     $ret[1] = 100;
     return $ret;
}
```

What's the correct syntax for this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35601314/2035600

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> **Note**, this is a legacy answer that's largely inapplicable for the current PHP versions. Please see the [answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37609954/) for the correct approach.

PHP cannot do this *yet*, it's a well-known limitation. You have every right to be wondering "are you kidding me?". Sorry.

If you don't mind generating an [`E_STRICT`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.constants.php) warning you can always pull out the first and last elements of an array with [`reset`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.reset.php) and [`end`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.end.php) respectively -- this means that you can also pull out *any* element since [`array_slice`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) can arrange for the one you want to remain first or last, but that's perhaps taking things too far.

But despair not: the (at this time upcoming) PHP 5.4 release will include exactly this feature (under the name [array dereferencing](http://schlueters.de/blog/archives/138-Features-in-PHP-trunk-Array-dereferencing.html)).

**Update:** I just thought of another technique which would work. There's probably good reason that I 've never used this or seen it used, but technically it does the job.

```
// To pull out Nth item of array:
list($item) = array_slice(getSomeArray(), N - 1, 1);
```

Comment: wow... how bizarre... ok... no worries... I'll pass it through a temp holder array. Thanks very much.

Comment: added in PHP 5.4 see below

Answer (score 6):

PHP 5.4 has added **Array Dereferencing**,
here's the example from PHP's Array documentation:

**Example #7 Array dereferencing**

```
function getArray() {
    return ['a', 'b', 'c'];
}

// PHP 5.4
$secondElement = getArray()[0]; // output = a

// Previously
$tmp = getArray();
$secondElement = $tmp[0]; // output = a
```

Answer (score 2):

The syntax you're referring to is known as function array dereferencing. It's not yet implemented and there's an [RFC for it](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/functionarraydereferencing).

The generally accepted syntax is to assign the return value of the function to an array and access the value from that with the `$array[1]`syntax.

That said, however you could also pass the key you want as an argument to your function.

```
function getSomeArray( $key = null ) {
  $array = array(
     0 => "cheddar",
     1 => "wensleydale"
  );

  return is_null($key) ? $array : isset( $array[$key] ) ? $array[$key] : false;    
}

echo getSomeArray(0); // only key 0
echo getSomeArray(); // entire array
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, php can't do that. Bat you can use [ArrayObect](http://php.net/manual/en/class.arrayobject.php), like so:

```
$item = getSomeArray()->{1};
// Credits for curly braces for Bracketworks    

function getSomeArray(){
     $ret = Array();
     $ret[0] = 0;
     $ret[1] = 100;
     return new ArrayObject($ret, ArrayObject::ARRAY_AS_PROPS);
}
```

Okay, maybe not working with numeric keys, but i'm not sure.

Comment: That'll raise a fatal; you need to do `getSomeArray()->{1};` Use curly braces for any non-compliant property names; see [SimpleXML](http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php)'s basic usage for related information.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but, in your example, you could also use `array_pop()` to get the last element of the array, (or `array_shift()` to get the first).

```
<?php
$item = array_pop(getSomeArray());


function getSomeArray(){
    $ret = Array();
    $ret[0] = 0;
    $ret[1] = 100;
    return $ret;
}
```

Comment: thanks... that wasn't at all my intention, though I can see with an array of 2 items how it can be misconstrued as what I'm looking for.  I was trying to figure out how to get array elements directly returned by a function.  I have since abandoned PHP as the giant steaming turd that it is and have not looked back.  Thanks though! :)

Answer (score 0):

As the others says, there is no direct way to do this, I usually just assign it to a variable like so:

```
$items = getSomeArray();
$item = $items[1];


function getSomeArray(){
    $ret = Array();
    $ret[0] = 0;
    $ret[1] = 100;
    return $ret;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am fairly certain that is not possible to do in PHP.  You have to assign the returned array to another array before you can access the elements within or use it directly in some other function that will iterate though the returned array (i.e. var_dump(getSomeArray()) ).