# Accessing arrays in place

Tags: php

I've seen people write code like this:

```
$image_url =  wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), array(300, 300), false, ''); 
$image_url = $image_url[0];
```

which seems a little ridiculous because you could just attach the [0] to the end of the first term. So I never did it in my local machine, but now when deploying to remote machines (with possibly different versions of php, I always get bugs about unexpected '['. Does php not accept accessing arrays in-place, or was there some change in some version?

Comment: I believe it's just a bad practice.
Semantics over "saving 14 characters"

Comment: You could also do `array_shift(...);` to get the zero-index. A simpler example could be: `$fileExt = array_pop(explode('.', $filename));` (`array_pop()` simply is the inverse of `array_shift()`).

Comment: and [Getting element from PHP array returned by function](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8888591)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is allowed since [PHP 5.4](http://php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php):

> Function array dereferencing has been added, e.g. foo()[0].

Comment: This caused **far** too much headache for me. Thanks for the clarity.

Answer (score 1):

Which version of PHP are you using? *Function array dereferencing* is allowed in PHP 5.4 (and above).

Answer (score 1):

In [PHP < 5.4](http://php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php), you can't take an element from an array before it exists... You must come from a Python or Ruby world where this kind of syntax is allowed.

If you have PHP < 5.4, you have to set the array and after get the index you want.

Comment: Javascript and I'm sure other languages also allow array dereferencing.

Comment: Python or Ruby... or C or Java or JavaScript or pretty much any other language.

Comment: I quoted the two first languages which came in my mind. A lot (almost all?) allowed that now.