# How to access an array element without assigning an array variable?

Tags: php

For example:

```
echo explode('@',$var); //but only echoing element 1 or 2 of the array?
```

Instead of:

```
$variable = explode('@',$var);
echo $variable[0];
```

Thank you.

Comment: Can the downvoter explain himself ?

Comment: Explode converts string to array. How can you access array element while it is a string ?

Comment: I did try to solve the problem, but to no avail. I have about 6 months experience with PHP, and nothing has stuck out in what i have read in how to solve this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: Access Array Value on the Fly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13109/php-access-array-value-on-the-fly)

Comment: @OBV: Here's a demo using `list()` that doesn't use temporary variables or additional function calls -- https://eval.in/54886

Comment: thnx for the added method

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35601314/2035600

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since PHP 5.4 you can write:

```
echo explode('@', $var)[0];
```

In earlier versions of PHP you can only achieve the behaviour with tricks:

```
echo current(explode('@', $var)); // get [0]
echo next(explode('@', $var));    // get [1]
```

Retreiving an element at an arbitrary position is not possible without a temporary variable.

---

Here is a simple function that can tidy your code if you don't want to use a variable every time:

```
function GetAt($arr, $key = 0)
{
    return $arr[$key];
}
```

Call like:

```
echo GetAt(explode('@', $var));    // get [0]
echo GetAt(explode('@', $var), 1); // get [1]
```

Comment: Technically it was possible, you could do `echo current(explode('@', $var));`

Comment: do those same tricks work in <5.4 aswell? I am looking for a general solution and not worry about the compatability issues

Comment: @OBV Yes, this behaviour should still be functional in 5.4 and later versions. The safest bet is probably a temporary variable though.

Comment: @OBV They do work, although I'm not sure how far back they'd work. Regardless, I wouldn't recommend using them as they disregard PHP Strict Standard rules. There's no real reason to not just assign it to a variable, 1 line of code is nothing and it's just considerably better practice to do so.

Comment: I tested: $var = "@hello@world";
echo current(explode('@', $var)); 
echo next(explode('@', $var)); and only "hello" appeared, any ideas?

Comment: @OBV There is nothing in front of your first `@`, so `current()` returns an empty string.

Comment: Lets just hope, that no one will take most bottom example too literally. Because it will be completely ineffective (:

Answer (score 7):

On PHP versions that support array dereferencing, you can use the following syntax:

```
echo explode('@', $var)[0];
```

If not, you can use [`list()`](http://php.net/list):

```
list($foo) = explode('@', $var);
```

The above statement will assign the first value of the exploded array in the variable `$foo`.

Answer (score 1):

Previous to PHP 5.4 you could do this:

```
echo array_shift(explode('@', $var));
```

That would echo the first element of the array created by explode. But it is doing so without error checking the output of explode, which is not ideal.

Answer (score 1):

`list` can be used like this as well:

```
list($first) = explode('@', $var);
list(,$second) = explode('@', $var);
list(,,$third) = explode('@', $var);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `reset` like this

```
echo reset(explode('@', $var));
```

Comment: I made a test before to post... It works find for me! `exit(reset(explode('-', 'it-is-my-test')));`