# Set Variable to specific element of an array returned by function

Tags: php

still learning some of the finer parts of PHP, i have a function that returns an array of arrays.  And on the times that it is only returning a single "array" i use the below code to save having to reference it as a multi dimensional array.  Is there a way to do this on a single line of code?  i know it doesnt make much of a differance in this specific scenrio, but just curious if i am missing a short hand of php that might be handy other times.

```
$res_resource=fetch($stmt_resource);  //returns array of arrays
$res_resource=$res_resource[0];
```

Comment: You could also try `current()` or other array-pointer functions: http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.current.php

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35601314/2035600

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of PHP 5.4.0:

```
$res_resource = fetch($stmt_resource)[0];
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I actually tried this, but Dreamweaver views it as an error, so i assumed it didnt work.  While this does work in php 5.4, unfortunetly because Dreamweaver views it as an error, code hint stops working, which is not a good trade off :-D.   Thank you again for your response, and this definetly works and functions as intended.