# getting data array in array in array

Tags: php, arrays

i tried to getting data array in array in array. have 3 level. if array in array i get it. but 3 level i can't. i want get attribute name and option in product id 315. i was successed get id variations 316 on product 315.

this sample data i tried to get

```
stdClass Object
(
[products] => Array
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [title] => Banner
                [id] => 315
                 [variations] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [id] => 316
                                [created_at] => 2019-04-13T09:21:55Z
                                   [attributes] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => stdClass Object
                                            (
                                                [name] => bahan
                                                [slug] => bahan
                                                [option] => Flexi 240gsm
                                            )

                                        [1] => stdClass Object
                                            (
                                                [name] => finising
                                                [slug] => finising
                                                [option] => Mata Ayam
                                            )

                                    )
                                  )
                     )
                 )
                 )
                 )
```

this a little my script..

```
<?php

 $values     = array();
 foreach ($results->products as $result) 
 {
   foreach ($result->variations as $varia) 
    {
    $values[] = "(  
                    '".$varia->id."', //ok
                    '".$result->id."', //ok
                    '".$varia->$attributes->$name."' //error
                ")
  }
}
```

?>

Comment: You need to either loop again over `attributes`, or access a specific element of it.

Comment: This, and you should drop the `$` before attributes, it's a field not a varible.

Comment: when i add one more loops is getting error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: Access Array Value on the Fly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13109/php-access-array-value-on-the-fly)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attributtes its an array. You need other loop

```
<?php

 $values     = array();
 foreach ($results->products as $result) 
 {
   foreach ($result->variations as $varia) 
    {
        foreach($varia->attributes as $attrib)
        {
              $values[] = "(  
                    '".$varia->id."', //ok
                    '".$result->id."', //ok
                    '".$attrib->name."'
                ")

        }

  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You made two mistakes: first attributes is an array, you have to loop over it.

Second, you are trying to access the attributes and name fields with an incorrect notation (the `$` in front of the field name is another functionality called [dynamic variables](https://www.php.net/manual/language.variables.variable.php), or variable variables)

```php
<?php

$values = [];
foreach ($results->products as $result) {
    foreach ($result->variations as $varia) {
        foreach ($varia->attributes as $attribute) {
            $values[] = "(
                    '" . $varia->id . "', //ok
                    '" . $result->id . "', //ok
                    '" . $attribute->name . "''
                )";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you still has issues with it, maybe you can try to dump your outputs? You probably nows [print_r](https://www.php.net/manual/function.print-r.php), which can help you debugging this type of problems

Comment: it works. thank you. but the output become more than one. it should just one product have 2 atribute. when use foreach more it become 2 product.

Comment: Well yeah, because each different attributes has a different name.

Comment: can u share idea get 1 product and have name with two attribute in just one row in one table. because if my idea is insert product in product table and attribute in another table and when i get the data just join.